# Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

How do I go about setting a `<div>` in the center of the screen using jQuery?

Comment: This is more of a CSS question than a jQuery question.  You can use jQuery methods to help you find the cross-browser positioning and to apply the proper CSS styles to an element, but the essence of the question is how to center a div on the screen using CSS.

Comment: Here is one more plugin. http://www.alexandremagno.net/jquery/plugins/center/

Comment: If you are centering a div on the screen, you may be using FIXED positioning. Why not just do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/margin-to-center-with-position-fixed. The solution is pure CSS, doesn't require javascript.

Answer (score 1086, accepted):

I like adding functions to jQuery so this function would help:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                                $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                                $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
}
```

Now we can just write:

```
$(element).center();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/GbDw9/) (with added parameter)

Comment: One change I'd suggest: You should use this.outerHeight() and this.outerWidth() instead of just this.height() and this.width(). Otherwise, if the object has a border or padding, it will end up slightly off-center.

Comment: I found that this worked great except in IE7/IE8 compatibility mode, where my element was shunted to the right by a fair bit. molokoloco's below solution worked cross-browser for me.

Comment: But outherHeight and outerWidth are only supported by Firefox, right?

Comment: Why isn't this a native part of jQuery's functionality?

Comment: This plugin/function works amazingly. I'm wondering, though, if it's possible to also add corner alignment options such as .bottomRight() or .leftTop() or something similar?

Comment: What if I dont want to center in the containing `<div>` instead of `<body>`? Maybe you should change `window` to `this.parent()` or add a parameter for it.

Comment: One problem with this is that if the element is higher or wider than the window then it will end up being placed with a negative top or left positioning meaning the user will not be able to scroll and see the whole thing. You should set top and left to 0 if they end up being negative.

Comment: I believe you should subtract half the height of the div you want to center, ie add this to the "top" code: `- (this.outerHeight() / 2)`

Comment: The code in the answer should use "position: fixed" since "absolute" is calculated from the first relative parent, and the code uses window to calculate the center.

Comment: I would also suggest adding support so that when the window is resized it'll adjust the element on the page.  Currently it stays with the original dimensions.

Comment: This is a great piece of code that I am now using to help with my custom fixes to the jQuery UI Dialog functionality (auto height + max height = jQuery UI Dialog no like). I modified the code slightly so that if the element being centered doesn't fit into the entire window, the top and left are set to the maximum values required to ensure that the top and left of the element are always visible. This works great for things like dialog boxes so the user can always access the title bar of the dialog box to move and close it. The fork of his code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/m6D72/

Comment: Instead of this.outerHeight() should be $(this).outerHeight() sameas $(this).outerWidth(). Otherwise you probably get "outerHeight is not a function" error. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947692/outerheight-is-not-a-function)

Comment: jQuery already has a center function.. Why don't you change the name!

Comment: To use fixed positioning instead of absolute, just remove the `+ $(window).scrollTop()` and `+ $(window).scrollLeft()`. (And, of course, change `"absolute"` to `"fixed"`).

Comment: thanks mate, Im declare my custom code to center any element, buts now when I read your function, really is very nice, ease ..Im like it very much, I will use this Now ^_^...nice..

Comment: This is fantastic, however... how would I make this a toggle? ...so that I can revert the centering in a different scenario? aka.. $(element).nocenter();

Comment: Why use $(this).outerHeight() instead of this.outerHeight()?

Comment: How would you animate this?

Answer (score 151):

I put a [jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/autocenter) here

VERY SHORT VERSION

```
$('#myDiv').css({top:'50%',left:'50%',margin:'-'+($('#myDiv').height() / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+($('#myDiv').width() / 2)+'px'});
```

SHORT VERSION

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        center: function () {
            return this.each(function() {
                var top = ($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2;
                var left = ($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2;
                $(this).css({position:'absolute', margin:0, top: (top > 0 ? top : 0)+'px', left: (left > 0 ? left : 0)+'px'});
            });
        }
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Activated by this code :

```
$('#mainDiv').center();
```

PLUGIN VERSION

```
(function($){
     $.fn.extend({
          center: function (options) {
               var options =  $.extend({ // Default values
                    inside:window, // element, center into window
                    transition: 0, // millisecond, transition time
                    minX:0, // pixel, minimum left element value
                    minY:0, // pixel, minimum top element value
                    withScrolling:true, // booleen, take care of the scrollbar (scrollTop)
                    vertical:true, // booleen, center vertical
                    horizontal:true // booleen, center horizontal
               }, options);
               return this.each(function() {
                    var props = {position:'absolute'};
                    if (options.vertical) {
                         var top = ($(options.inside).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2;
                         if (options.withScrolling) top += $(options.inside).scrollTop() || 0;
                         top = (top > options.minY ? top : options.minY);
                         $.extend(props, {top: top+'px'});
                    }
                    if (options.horizontal) {
                          var left = ($(options.inside).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2;
                          if (options.withScrolling) left += $(options.inside).scrollLeft() || 0;
                          left = (left > options.minX ? left : options.minX);
                          $.extend(props, {left: left+'px'});
                    }
                    if (options.transition > 0) $(this).animate(props, options.transition);
                    else $(this).css(props);
                    return $(this);
               });
          }
     });
})(jQuery);
```

Activated by this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainDiv').center();
    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        $('#mainDiv').center({transition:300});
    });
);
```

is that right ?

## UPDATE :

From [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/)

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Yep! */
  width: 48%;
  height: 59%;
}
```

Comment: Your function worked perfectly fine for a vertical center.  It does not appear to work for a horizontal center.

Comment: The CSS assumes you know the size (percentages at least) of the centered div, whereas the jQuery works whatever.

Comment: My vote is CSS - much more straightforward and doesn't need any fancy Java script.  If you use fixed instead of absolute it'll stay in center of page even when the user scrolls the browser window

Answer (score 63):

I would recommend [jQueryUI Position utility](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/)

```
$('your-selector').position({
    of: $(window)
});
```

which gives you much more possibilities than only centering ...

Comment: @Timwi - Are you sure you are centering on window vs. document?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).position is not a function

Comment: @Michelangelo: You need the jqueryUI library to use .position() as a function.  Check out: api.jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: That snippet is the best :D. But be warn the element must be "visible".'

Answer (score 40):

Here's my go at it. I ended up using it for my Lightbox clone. The main advantage of this solution is that the element will stay centered automatically even if the window is resized making it ideal for this sort of usage.

```
$.fn.center = function() {
    this.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'left': '50%',
        'top': '50%'
    });
    this.css({
        'margin-left': -this.outerWidth() / 2 + 'px',
        'margin-top': -this.outerHeight() / 2 + 'px'
    });

    return this;
}
```

Comment: I think this works well... it went wrong in my case because of using responsive design: my div's width changes as screen width changes. What does work perfectly is Tony L's answer and then adding this: `$(window).resize(function(){$('#mydiv').center()});`  (mydiv is a modal dialog, so when it is closed I remove the resize event handler.)

Comment: Sometimes you may want to use `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()` to consider padding and border width.

Comment: This works perfectly for me for legacy project with doc type 5 where `$(window).height()` gives 0. But I've changed position to 'absolute'.

Answer (score 27):

You can use CSS alone to center like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/e4y6F/)**

```css
.center{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background:red;
    top:calc(50% - 50px/2); /* height divided by 2*/
    left:calc(50% - 50px/2); /* width divided by 2*/
}
```

```html
<div class="center"></div>
```

`calc()` allows you to do basic calculations in css.

[MDN Documentation for `calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
[Browser support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: Keep in mind calc() is not supported in IE8 if you need to support that browser use the jquery center strategy.

Answer (score 15):

I'm expanding upon the great answer given by @TonyL. I'm adding Math.abs() to wrap the values, and also I take into account that jQuery might be in "no conflict" mode, like for instance in WordPress.

I recommend that you wrap the top and left values with Math.abs() as I have done below. If the window is too small, and your modal dialog has a close box at the top, this will prevent the problem of not seeing the close box. Tony's function would have had potentially negative values. A good example on how you end up with negative values is if you have a large centered dialog but the end user has installed several toolbars and/or increased his default font -- in such a case, the close box on a modal dialog (if at the top) might not be visible and clickable.

The other thing I do is speed this up a bit by caching the $(window) object so that I reduce extra DOM traversals, and I use a cluster CSS.

```
jQuery.fn.center = function ($) {
  var w = $(window);
  this.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'top':Math.abs(((w.height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + w.scrollTop()),
    'left':Math.abs(((w.width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + w.scrollLeft())
  });
  return this;
}
```

To use, you would do something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#myelem').center();
});
```

Comment: I like your improvements; however, there is still one issue I found depending on the exact behavior you are looking for. The abs will work great only if the user is fully scrolled to the top and left, otherwise the user will have to scroll the browser window to get to the title bar. To solve that problem I opted to do a simple if statement such as this: `if (top < w.scrollTop()) top = w.scrollTop();` along with the equivalent for left. Again, this provides different behavior that may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 12):

I would use the **[jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)** `position` function.

**[See working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ADm97/1/)**.

```
<div id="test" style="position:absolute;background-color:blue;color:white">
    test div to center in window
</div>
```

If i have a div with id "test" to center then the following script would center the div in the window on document ready. (the default values for "my" and "at" in the position options are "center")

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#test").position({
     of: $(window)
  });
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

I would like to correct one issue.

```
this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
```

Above code won't work in cases when `this.height` (lets assume that user resizes the screen and content is dynamic) and `scrollTop() = 0`, example:

`window.height` is `600`
`this.height` is `650`

```
600 - 650 = -50  

-50 / 2 = -25
```

Now the box is centered `-25` offscreen.

Answer (score 7):

This is untested, but something like this should work.

```
var myElement = $('#myElement');
myElement.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '50%',
    'margin-left': 0 - (myElement.width() / 2)
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I dont think having an absolute position would be best if you want an element always centered in the middle of the page. You probably want a fixed element. I found another jquery centering plugin that used fixed positioning. It is called [fixed center](http://david-tang.net/2010/06/fixed-center-plugin/).

Answer (score 5):

### Edit:

If the question taught me anything, it's this: don't change something that already works :)

I'm providing an (almost) verbatim copy of how this was handled on http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html - it's heavily hacked for IE but provides a pure CSS way of answering the question:

```css
.container {display:table; height:100%; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; width:100%;}
.helper    {#position:absolute; #top:50%;
            display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
.content   {#position:relative; #top:-50%;
            margin:0 auto; width:200px; border:1px solid orange;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S9upd/4/

I've run this through browsershots and it seems fine; if for nothing else, I'll keep the original below so that margin percentage handling as dictated by CSS spec sees the light of day.

### Original:

Looks like I'm late to the party!

There are some comments above that suggest this is a CSS question - separation of concerns and all. Let me preface this by saying that CSS *really* shot itself in the foot on this one. I mean, how easy would it be to do this:

```css
.container {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    overflow:visible;
}
.content {
    position:relative;
    margin:-50% 50% 50% -50%;
}
```

Right? Container's top left corner would be in the center of the screen, and with negative margins the content will magically reappear in the absolute center of the page! http://jsfiddle.net/rJPPc/

***Wrong!*** Horizontal positioning is OK, but vertically... Oh, I see. Apparently in css, when setting top margins in %, the value is calculated as [a percentage always relative to the **width** of the containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/margin-top). Like apples and oranges! If you don't trust me or Mozilla doco, have a play with the fiddle above by adjusting content width and be amazed.

---

Now, with CSS being my bread and butter, I was not about to give up. At the same time, I prefer things easy, so I've borrowed the findings of a [Czech CSS guru](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) and made it into a working fiddle. Long story short, we create a table in which vertical-align is set to middle:

```html
<table class="super-centered"><tr><td>
    <div class="content">
        <p>I am centered like a boss!</p>
    </div>
</td></tr></table>
```

And than the content's position is fine-tuned with good old **margin:0 auto;**:

```css
.super-centered {position:absolute; width:100%;height:100%;vertical-align:middle;}
.content {margin:0 auto;width:200px;}​
```

Working fiddle as promised: http://jsfiddle.net/teDQ2/

Comment: The problem is that isn't centered.

Comment: @GlitchMr: I'd like to double check on the work box tomorrow, but the second fiddle worked fine on Chrome/Safari Mac

Comment: Right, I've checked in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 8+ (IE7 doesn't work) and it works. But it doesn't work in Opera... and that's very weird considering it's simple CSS and it works in other browsers.

Comment: @GlitchMr: thanks for keeping an eye on such an old question. I've updated the fiddle link above to show a "correct" answer - let me know if it works for you (or downvote into oblivion. I've had my chance! :)

Comment: Heh, all I will do is not upvoting unless proper answer will show (currently it still doesn't work in Opera, but I think it's browser bug)... oh wait... it works if I will resize the window and not if I will resize windows in JSFiddle itself. So, it works :). I'm sorry for this. But still, you should put warning that it doesn't work in IE7. +1. Oh, and I think it works in IE6...

Comment: Actually, my mistake. I haven't read and I thought that you've updated lowest fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/teDQ2/). Current solution works fine in IE7.

Answer (score 4):

The transition component of this function worked really poorly for me in Chrome (didn't test elsewhere). I would resize the window a bunch and my element would sort of scoot around slowly, trying to catch up.

So the following function comments that part out. In addition, I added parameters for passing in optional x & y booleans, if you want to center vertically but not horizontally, for example:

```
// Center an element on the screen
(function($){
  $.fn.extend({
    center: function (x,y) {
      // var options =  $.extend({transition:300, minX:0, minY:0}, options);
      return this.each(function() {
                if (x == undefined) {
                    x = true;
                }
                if (y == undefined) {
                    y = true;
                }
                var $this = $(this);
                var $window = $(window);
                $this.css({
                    position: "absolute",
                });
                if (x) {
                    var left = ($window.width() - $this.outerWidth())/2+$window.scrollLeft();
                    $this.css('left',left)
                }
                if (!y == false) {
            var top = ($window.height() - $this.outerHeight())/2+$window.scrollTop();   
                    $this.css('top',top);
                }
        // $(this).animate({
        //   top: (top > options.minY ? top : options.minY)+'px',
        //   left: (left > options.minX ? left : options.minX)+'px'
        // }, options.transition);
        return $(this);
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is great.  I added a callback function

```
center: function (options, callback) {
```

```
if (options.transition > 0) {
   $(this).animate(props, options.transition, callback);
} else { 
    $(this).css(props);
   if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
       callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To center the element relative to the browser viewport (window), don't use `position: absolute`, the correct position value should be `fixed` (absolute means: "The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element").

This alternative version of the proposed center plugin uses "%" instead of "px" so when you resize the window the content is keep centered:

```
$.fn.center = function () {
    var heightRatio = ($(window).height() != 0) 
            ? this.outerHeight() / $(window).height() : 1;
    var widthRatio = ($(window).width() != 0) 
            ? this.outerWidth() / $(window).width() : 1;

    this.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        margin: 0,
        top: (50*(1-heightRatio)) + "%",
        left: (50*(1-widthRatio))  + "%"
    });

    return this;
}
```

You need to put `margin: 0` to exclude the content margins from the width/height (since we are using position fixed, having margins makes no sense). 
According to the jQuery doc using `.outerWidth(true)` should include margins, but it didn't work as expected when I tried in Chrome.

The `50*(1-ratio)` comes from:

Window Width: `W = 100%`

Element Width (in %): `w = 100 * elementWidthInPixels/windowWidthInPixels`

Them to calcule the centered left:

```
 left = W/2 - w/2 = 50 - 50 * elementWidthInPixels/windowWidthInPixels =
 = 50 * (1-elementWidthInPixels/windowWidthInPixels)
```

Answer (score 3):

What I have here is a "center" method that ensures the element you are attempting to center is not only of "fixed" or "absolute" positioning, but it also ensures that the element you are centering is smaller than its parent, this centers and element relative to is parent, if the elements parent is smaller than the element itself, it will pillage up the DOM to the next parent, and center it relative to that.

```
$.fn.center = function () {
        /// <summary>Centers a Fixed or Absolute positioned element relative to its parent</summary>

        var element = $(this),
            elementPos = element.css('position'),
            elementParent = $(element.parent()),
            elementWidth = element.outerWidth(),
            parentWidth = elementParent.width();

        if (parentWidth <= elementWidth) {
            elementParent = $(elementParent.parent());
            parentWidth = elementParent.width();
        }

        if (elementPos === "absolute" || elementPos === "fixed") {
            element.css('right', (parentWidth / 2) - elementWidth / 2 + 'px');
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

**CSS solution**
**In two lines only**

It centralize your inner div horizontally and vertically.

```
#outer{
  display: flex;
}
#inner{
  margin: auto;
}
```

for only horizontal align, change

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

and for vertical, change

```
margin: auto 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

i use this:

```
$(function() {
   $('#divId').css({
    'left' : '50%',
    'top' : '50%',
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'margin-left' : -$('#divId').outerWidth()/2,
    'margin-top' : -$('#divId').outerHeight()/2
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.className').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
    });
});

// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

you're getting that poor transition because you're adjusting the position of the element every time the document is scrolled. What you want is to use fixed positioning. I tried that fixed center plugin listed above and that seems to do solve the problem nicely. Fixed positioning allows you to center an element once, and the CSS property will take care of maintaining that position for you every time you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version. I may change it after I look at these examples.

```
$.fn.pixels = function(property){
    return parseInt(this.css(property));
};

$.fn.center = function(){
    var w = $($w);
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).css("position","absolute");
        $(this).css("top",((w.height() - $(this).height()) / 2) - (($(this).pixels('padding-top') + $(this).pixels('padding-bottom')) / 2) + w.scrollTop() + "px");
        $(this).css("left",((w.width() - $(this).width()) / 2) - (($(this).pixels('padding-left') + $(this).pixels('padding-right')) / 2) + w.scrollLeft() + "px");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No need jquery for this

I used this to center  Div element.
Css Style,

```
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 16px solid orange;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Open element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open").click(function(e){
      $(".black_overlay").fadeIn(200);
    });

});
```

Comment: Did you forget to include the html to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS `translate` property:

```
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Read [this post](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/07/30/centering-a-div-with-css-without-negative-margin-or-jquery/) for more details.

Comment: For something like that, you would want to set your `left: 50%` and `top: 50%` then you can use the transform translate to shift its center point over correctly. However, with this method, browsers such as Chrome will distort/blur your text afterwards, which isn't usually desirable. It's better to grab the width/height of the window, and then position the left/top based upon that instead of messing with the transform. Prevents distortion and works across every browser I've tested it on.

Answer (score 0):

**MY UPDATE TO TONY L'S ANSWER**
This is the modded version of his answer that I use religiously now. I thought I would share it, as it adds slightly more functionality to it for various situations you may have, such as different types of `position` or only wanting horizontal/vertical centering rather than both.

center.js:

```
// We add a pos parameter so we can specify which position type we want

// Center it both horizontally and vertically (dead center)
jQuery.fn.center = function (pos) {
    this.css("position", pos);
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    return this;
}

// Center it horizontally only
jQuery.fn.centerHor = function (pos) {
    this.css("position", pos);
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    return this;
}

// Center it vertically only
jQuery.fn.centerVer = function (pos) {
    this.css("position", pos);
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    return this;
}
```

In my `<head>`:

```
<script src="scripts/center.js"></script>
```

Examples of usage:

```
$("#example1").centerHor("absolute")
$("#example2").centerHor("fixed")

$("#example3").centerVer("absolute")
$("#example4").centerVer("fixed")

$("#example5").center("absolute")
$("#example6").center("fixed")
```

It works with any positioning type, and can be used throughout your entire site easily, as well as easily portable to any other site you create. No more annoying workarounds for centering something properly.

Hope this is useful for someone out there! Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of ways to do this. My object is kept hidden with **display:none** just inside the BODY tag so that positioning is relative to the BODY. After using **$("#object_id").show()**, I call **$("#object_id").center()**

I use **position:absolute** because it is possible, especially on a small mobile device, that the modal window is larger than the device window, in which case some of the modal content could be inaccessible if positioning was fixed.

Here's my flavor based on other's answers and my specific needs:

```
$.fn.center = function () {
        this.css("position","absolute");

        //use % so that modal window will adjust with browser resizing
        this.css("top","50%");
        this.css("left","50%");

        //use negative margin to center
        this.css("margin-left",(-1*this.outerWidth()/2)+($(window).scrollLeft())+"px");
        this.css("margin-top",(-1*this.outerHeight()/2)+($(window).scrollTop())+"px");

        //catch cases where object would be offscreen
        if(this.offset().top<0)this.css({"top":"5px","margin-top":"0"});
        if(this.offset().left<0)this.css({"left":"5px","margin-left":"0"});

        return this;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would do this with CSS only... but since you asked you a way to do this with jQuery...

The following code centers a div both horizontally and vertically inside its container :

```js
$("#target").addClass("centered-content")
            .wrap("<div class='center-outer-container'></div>")
            .wrap("<div class='center-inner-container'></div>");
```

```css
body {
    margin : 0;
    background: #ccc;
}

.center-outer-container {
    position : absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.center-inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 20px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">Center this!</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3k1ts96b/1/))

Answer (score 0):

Just say:
$("#divID").html($('').html($("#divID").html()));

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with only **CSS**. But they asked with **jQuery or JavaScript**

Here, use **[`CSS Flex box`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** property to align the div center.

```
body.center{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center; // Vertical alignment
  justify-content:center; // Horizontal alignment
}
```

> **[align-items:center;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)** - used to align vertically.

> **[justify-content:center;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)** - used to align horizontally.

```js
document.querySelector("body").classList.add("center");
```

```css
body {
  margin : 0;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
#main{
  background:#00cc00;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
body.center{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to put the UL in the middle position.

```
cadasWidth          = $('.card-dashboard').innerWidth();
cadasWidthCenter    = cadasWidth/2;

ulmenuWidth         = $('.card-dashboard ul#menu').outerWidth();
ulmenuWidthCenter   = ulmenuWidth/2;

ulmenuStart = cadasWidthCenter - ulmenuWidthCenter;

$('.card-dashboard ul#menu').css({
    'left' : ulmenuStart,
    'position' : 'relative'
});
```

Answer (score -7):

Why you don't use CSS for centering a div?

```
#timer_wrap{  
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: In your example, the div's top/left will be where the center supposed to be.