# Any alternative to blockUI for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, blockui

The question says it all! **I am looking for an easy to use alternative of blockUI for jQuery**. I've been trying for days to center a dialog box with blockUI in both FireFox and IE but no chance. It doesn't work. I looked at this question about centering a blockUI dialog box ([How can I get a DIV to centre on a page using jQuery and blockUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294502/how-can-i-get-a-div-to-centre-on-a-page-using-jquery-and-blockui)) but it works only with Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dialog boxes, I have switched from blockUI to [Jquery UI](http://ui.jquery.com/demos/dialog).  I think it's better.

Comment: Just make sure you get your css / jquery ui theme correct or you'll still be able to click the background of the page :)

Answer (score 6):

you might want to check this plugin call [jQuery MSG](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/jquery-blockui-alternative-with-jquery-msg-plugin/). It works great in most of the browsers including ie6. And it is very light weight, only 4k uncompressed with code comments.

#### Example code

```
// this will block the page and shows a `please wait` message
$.msg();

// you can change the content by the following code
$.msg({
  content : '<img src="loading.gif"/> Sending mail :)'
});
```

[Demo page](http://dreamerslab.com/demos/jquery-blockui-alternative-with-jquery-msg-plugin)

Source code on [github](https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.msg)

Full documentation and usage please check [this post](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/jquery-blockui-alternative-with-jquery-msg-plugin/)

or if you just want to centralize some DOM element you can take a look at this [jQuery Center plugin](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/centralize-html-dom-element-with-jquery-center-plugin/)

Comment: this plugin does support blocking of elements. It just puts overlay to whole window

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension which I came across and modified slightly. Looking at it now, I think it's actually a bit messy and could use a clean up (there's some unused variables I think)

```
$.fn.vCenter = function(options) {
    var pos = {
        sTop : function() {
            return window.pageYOffset || $.boxModel && document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
        },
        wHeight : function() {
            if ($.browser.opera || ($.browser.safari && parseInt($.browser.version) > 520)) {
                return window.innerHeight - (($ (document).height() > window.innerHeight) ? getScrollbarWidth() : 0);
            } else if ($.browser.safari) {
                return window.innerHeight;
            } else {
                return $.boxModel && document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
            }
        }
    };
    return this.each(function(index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            var $this = $(this),
                $w = $(window),
                topPos = ($w.height() - $this.height()) / 2 + $w.scrollTop()
            ;
            if (topPos < 0 && (options == undefined || !options.allowNegative)) topPos = 0;
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                marginTop: '0',
                top: topPos //pos.sTop() + (pos.wHeight() / 2) - (elHeight / 2)
            });
        }
    });
};
$.fn.hCenter = function(options) {
    return this.each(function(index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            var $this = $(this),
                $d = $(document),
                leftPos = ($d.width() - $this.width()) / 2 + $d.scrollLeft()
            ;
            if (leftPos < 0 && (options == undefined || !options.allowNegative)) leftPos = 0;
            $this.css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: leftPos
            });
        }
    });
};
$.fn.hvCenter = function(options) {
    return this.vCenter(options).hCenter(options);
};
```

Usage:

```
$('#verticalCenter').vCenter();
$('#horizontalCenter').hCenter();
$('#bothCentered').hvCenter();
```

Comment: Note this uses jQuery.browser which was removed in jQuery 1.9

Answer (score 0):

In case the problem is caused by loading the dimensions plugin along with the latest version of jQuery, then Dimensions was merged into the core a few versions ago and was causing a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

## Why don't I see overlays in FF on Linux?

Several people informed me that full page opacity rendering in FF/Linux is crazy slow, so by default it's disabled for that platform. You can enable it by overriding the applyPlatformOpacityRules property like this:

```
// enable transparent overlay on FF/Linux 
$.blockUI.defaults.applyPlatformOpacityRules = false;
```