# outerHeight is not a function?

Tags: jquery

Having trouble with this jQuery function:

```
$("#content").siblings().each(function(i){
  heightOfSiblings = heightOfSiblings + this.outerHeight();     
});
```

Error is 'outerHeight is not a function.'

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will need $(this).outerHeight();

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/outerHeight

Answer (score 1):

outerHeight is a property

```
heightOfSiblings = heightOfSiblings + this.outerHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Old thing but I have recently met the same problem and solution was to use the newest version of jQuery:)

Answer (score 0):

One can also get this error message if the element you are evaluating is null.

ie: if there's no element with an "elem" class, you get this error ("outerHeight is not a function"):

```
$(".elem").outerHeight();
```