# Centering element inside an element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, height, center, vertical-alignment

```
<div class="preview">
  <span class="center">This will be centered</div>
</div>
```

Preview has fixed width (120x120), but span may contain anything (image, text). How do I center it **vertically** and **horizontally** using **jQuery**? I looked up some snippets but they all center elements inside the 'body' not another element. I'd like to avoid use a 'plugin' for this if possible.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't mind using jQuery, you can use the [Center Element Plugin](https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.center)

It's as simple as doing:

```
$(".preview").center();
```

Answer (score 14):

The latest jQuery UI has a position component:

```
$("#myDialog").position({
   my: "center",
   at: "center",
   of: window
});
```

Doc: http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/
Get: http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: I don't know why this is -1.  It was just what I was looking for.  Super simple!  Wish I would of known of ui.position earlier!  Thanks Hugo.

Comment: He's using Jquery, not Jquery UI. Adding the weight of Jquery UI is unreasonable for simply centering.

Comment: android.nick - Did he specifically say he was not using jquery UI? +1 this worked great for me, already using jquery ui and was toying with another centering library that did not work. Thanks Hugo

Comment: I just yoinked the UI position module out of the UI package.  It works without any of the rest of the jQuery UI library.  Just use what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned you're using jquery, i assume you would like to do this via javascript. You can add styles to elements in the DOM using Jquery. You can use

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#properties

```
  $(.center).css({'display' : 'block', 'text-align' : 'center'});
```

Depending on the element, you may be able to center it without having to use text-align:center if you set the margin to

```
margin: 0 auto 0 auto
```

This will set the margin on the top and bottom to zero, and auto on the left and right, this can be used to center the block element inside of another block element.

To center an element vertically in jquery you can use this

http://cool-javascripts.com/jquery/vertical-alignment-of-contents-inside-an-element-using-jquery.html

```
    function ($) {
    $.fn.vAlign = function(container) {
        return this.each(function(i){
    if(container == null) {
       container = 'div';
    }
    var paddingPx = 10; //change this value as you need (It is the extra height for the parent element)
    $(this).html("<" + container + ">" + $(this).html() + "</" + container + ">");
    var el = $(this).children(container + ":first");
    var elh = $(el).height(); //new element height
    var ph = $(this).height(); //parent height
    if(elh > ph) { //if new element height is larger apply this to parent
        $(this).height(elh + paddingPx);
        ph = elh + paddingPx;
    }
    var nh = (ph - elh) / 2; //new margin to apply
    $(el).css('margin-top', nh);
        });
     };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CSS only solution (ignoring IE)

`<div class="preview"  style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;margin:0 auto">
  <span class="center">This will be centered</div>
</div>`

using display:block will also work but only for horizontal alignment, for vertical alignment either you will need to emulate a table as per the above code or alternatively use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your own function to jquery:

```
// Centers on div
jQuery.fn.center = function (div) {
this.css("position", "absolute");

var position = div.position();
this.css("top", Math.max(0, ((div.height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + position.top) + "px");

this.css("left", Math.max(0, ((div.width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + position.left) + "px");
return this;
};
```

Use:

```
$('#ajxload').center($('#mapWrapper')).show();
```

Took the concept from the code at [Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using CSS.
 This post provides a good solution - http://mindthesemicolon.com/how-to-center-an-element-vertically-and-horizontally-using-css/ 

Basically: 

1. Set the child to position absolute. 
2. Set the parent to position relative. 
3. Set child's left and top to 50%. 
4. translate(-50%,-50%) to shift left and top by half the width of the child element.