# Center a position:fixed element

Tags: css, css-position, centering

I would like to make a `position: fixed;` popup box centered to the screen with a dynamic width and height. I used `margin: 5% auto;` for this. Without `position: fixed;` it centers fine horizontally, but not vertically. After adding `position: fixed;`, it's even not centering horizontally.

Here's the complete set:

```css
.jqbox_innerhtml {
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5% auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="jqbox_innerhtml">
    This should be inside a horizontally
    and vertically centered box.
</div>
```

How do I center this box in screen with CSS?

Answer (score 803, accepted):

If your div has a known width and height, then you basically need to set `top` and `left` to `50%` to center the left-top corner of the div. You also need to set the `margin-top` and `margin-left` to the negative half of the div's height and width to shift the center towards the middle of the div.

```
position: fixed;
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -100px; /* Negative half of height. */
margin-left: -250px; /* Negative half of width. */
```

Or, if your div has a dynamic/undefined width and/or height, then instead of the `margin`, set the `transform` to the negative half of the div's relative width and height.

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Or, if your div has at least a fixed width and you don't really care about centering vertically, then you can instead also add `left: 0` and `right: 0` to the element having a `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `auto`, so that the fixed positioned element having a fixed width knows where its left and right offsets start. In your case thus:

```
position: fixed;
width: 500px;
margin: 5% auto; /* Only centers horizontally not vertically! */
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Comment: I found that trick in http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/. But when I change the width and height, it's not moving center. Ya, I should change the margin-left and top when change height and width.

Comment: FYI: this will correctly position things in the middle, but unfortunately you lose your scroll-bars - any content clipped off by the viewport won't be reachable, even if you scroll, because the fixed position is based on the viewport, not the page.  So far, the only solution I've found to that is with javascript.

Comment: Groxx I think you could put scroll bars inside a div in the pop up using the [overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Comment: Besides, for this one you need to know the element's width.

Comment: @saturngod For some reason the margin-top and margin-left are not working for me. But the alternative in the post you linked (translate -50% -50%) worked perfectly

Comment: @David: as outlined in the article, that's only necessary if the element doesn't have a fixed width/height. However, in OP's case, the element has a fixed width/height, so the `translate` is unnecessary.

Comment: Nice combination of margin: x auto with left:0 right:0 ;) worked perfectly!

Comment: Not sure why this get so many votes. It doesnt center correctly if the div is larger than 200px (height, but same for width)

Comment: BalusC: Arrogance. I read it ,yes: "set the margin-top and margin-left to the negative half of the div's height and width to shift the center towards the middle of the div."  -- so that makes it static width and height, right? Have you noticed the question specifically stated dynamic?

Comment: @nights: "dynamic" concerns the screen, not the element. So the element stays centered even when screen resizes. Have you read the question's code too? The element has a fixed width/height. Not sure why you're being so negative.

Comment: ah. nm if thats the case, i mean of course the browser size will be dynamic, not sure why that was in the question. instead i thought he meant that the popup dimensions needed to be dynamic. thats the case for me so im using  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   works great except not on IE8.

Answer (score 513):

> I want to make a popup box centered to the screen with dynamic width and height.

Here is a modern approach for horizontally centering an element with a dynamic width - it works in all modern browsers; [support can be seen here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vq08ruh2/)

```
.jqbox_innerhtml {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

For both vertical and horizontal centering you could use the following:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/utn2wa4x/)

```
.jqbox_innerhtml {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

You may wish to add in more vendor prefixed properties too (see the examples).

Comment: this messes up chrome. for very long divs, for whatever reason, it starts to aisle.

Comment: @dolphonebubleine Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I'm using this approach to horizontally center a fixed positioned image which width is greater than window width and working fine atleast in current Firefox, Chrome, IE 11 and Edge versions.

Comment: In my testing this works very well (behind prefixes), Win10 Edge 14, Win7 IE9+, Win10 Chrome, OSX Chrome, iPad4 Chrome & Safari, Android 4.4+ Chrome. Only failure for me was Android 4.0 where the translation did not occur.

Comment: @ahnbizcad, this works in desktop browsers like Chrome 61, Safari 11 and FireFox 65, but not in Chrome 61 on Android 6, the accepted answer works in all browsers.

Comment: This makes images blurry in Chrome.

Comment: Somehow only approach that worked proper across all browser with my img. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This seemed to work really well at first, but... anyone with drag-and-drop elements on their pages beware: this method created problems with [SortableJS](https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/) for me. The elements being dragged would, as soon as they were grabbed, jump to their *original* positions before `transform` gets calculated. I am now using a variation on [Will Prescot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2006091/2454914) instead, with no issues so far.

Answer (score 146):

Or just add `left: 0` and `right: 0` to your original CSS, which makes it behave similarly to a regular non-fixed element and the usual auto-margin technique works:

```
.jqbox_innerhtml
{
  position: fixed;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#FFF;
  padding:10px;
  border:5px solid #CCC;
  z-index:200;
  margin: 5% auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Note you need to use a valid (X)HTML `DOCTYPE` for it to behave correctly in IE (which you should of course have anyway..!)

Comment: In what sense? The parent element is the body element, which has no borders. If you added border properties to the body (?!) then sure it would be affected, as would the 50% technique I imagine. I assure you it works just fine with the given parameters, just verified in every browser I have handy, and has the added benefit of not being dependent on the width of the element.

Comment: All I did was add those 2 properties and a doctype to the OP's example HTML. However on further testing it seems that IE7 (or 8 in compat mode) is the problem - it seems it does not respect the value of the `right` property if `left` is also set! ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#positioning notes that `left` and `right` only have "partial" support in IE7). OK, I concede this solution is no good if IE7 support is important, but a great trick to remember for the future :)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. I had two fixed positions one for the opacity mask another for the modal.  this was the only way I could center the fixed position modal in the center of the screen.  Awesome answer who would have thought?

Comment: I agree, this should be the accepted answer. It works perfectly in responsive design, too, as it is not dependant on width.

Comment: I would suggest to simplify the answer, as some of the css is relevant only for the OP. All you need is position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; .

Comment: Can anyone explain *why* adding `left` and `right` makes `margin:0 auto` work?

Comment: @showdev Because `margin: auto` centres horizontally a fixed/absolutely positioned element only if values of `left`, `right` and `width` on this element aren't `auto`.

Comment: Worked for me with a `width:100%;` and a `max-width:1280px;`

Comment: that only works if the width is set (or max width)

Answer (score 35):

Add a container like:

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Then put your box into this div will do the work.

Edit: as mentioned in the comments, the inner content needs to be set to `display: inline-block` assuming there're two divs like:

```html
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
             content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then the CSS for the inner needs to be:

```
    .outer {
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .inner {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Together with the outer div having a `left: 0; right:0;` and `text-align: center` this will align the inner div centered, without explicitly specifying the width of the inner div.

Comment: "text-align: center" didn't work for me in centering the internal div.

Comment: The internal box needs to be `display: inline-block` for this to work.  (Some other display values might also work, such as `table`.)

Comment: a better approach to the above mentioned css would be adding `margin:auto;` and changing width to `width:50%` or `width:400px`. then the contents can be straight text, block elements, or inline elements.

Comment: This solution has the added benefit of not blurring the textual content in MSIE and Chrome which occurs when "transform" is used.

Answer (score 29):

Center fixed position element
(the simple & best way I know)

```
position:fixed;
top: 0; left: 0;
transform: translate(calc(50vw - 50%));
```

For centering it horizontally & vertically (if height is same as width)

```
position:fixed;
top: 0; left: 0;
transform: translate(calc(50vw - 50%), calc(50vh - 50%));
```

Both of these approaches will not limit centered element's width less than viewport width, when using margins in flexbox, inside centered element

Answer (score 27):

Just add:

```
left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
right: calc(-50vw + 50%);
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `position: fixed`, which is what the question is about. If I'm wrong, please edit your answer to include a runnable code snippet.

Comment: It works with `position: fixed`, provided set the `max-width` or `width` to the element.

Answer (score 11):

```
#modal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

inside it can be any element with diffenet width, height or without.
all are centered.

Answer (score 5):

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Was not working under IE7.

Changed to

```
left:auto;
right:auto;
```

Started working but in the rest browsers it stop working!
So used this way for IE7 below

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 7) {                                
  strAlertWrapper.css({position:'fixed', bottom:'0', height:'auto', left:'auto', right:'auto'});
}
```

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer to include the entire solution?

Comment: This won't work without an auto margin on left and right sides.

Answer (score 5):

This solution does not require of you to define a width and height to your popup div.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Ly4B/33/

And instead of calculating the size of the popup, and minus half to the top, javascript is resizeing the popupContainer to fill out the whole screen...

(100% height, does not work when useing display:table-cell; (wich is required to center something vertically))...

Anyway it works :)

Answer (score 4):

I used `vw` (viewport width) and `vh` (viewport height). viewport is your entire screen. `100vw` is your screens total width and `100vh` is total height.

```
.class_name{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 25vw;top: 25vh;   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can basically wrap it into another `div` and set its `position` to `fixed`.

```css
.bg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.jqbox_innerhtml {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="jqbox_innerhtml">
    This should be inside a horizontally and vertically centered box.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just use something like this:

```
.c-dialogbox {
    --width:  56rem;
    --height: 32rem;

    position: fixed;

    width:  var(--width);
    height: var(--height);
    left:   calc( ( 100% - var(--width) ) / 2 );
    right:  calc( ( 100% - var(--width) ) / 2 );
    top:    calc( ( 100% - var(--height) ) / 2 );
    bottom: calc( ( 100% - var(--height) ) / 2 );
}
```

It centers the dialog box both horizontally and vertically for me, and I can use different width and height to fit different screen resolutions to make it responsive, with media queries.

Not an option if you still need to provide support for browsers where CSS custom properties or `calc()` are not supported (check on caniuse.)

Answer (score 2):

This one worked the best for me:

```css
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the position use this :

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    left: 68%;
    transform: translateX(-8%);
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation on why your solution would work for the question posted.

Answer (score 1):

simple, try this

```
position: fixed;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
top: calc(50% - 150px);
left: calc(50% - 250px);
background-color: red;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set something like this

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One possible [answer](http://longterm.softf1.com/2013/stackoverflow_com/demos/2005954_center_element_with_positionfixed/demo_1/):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Center Background Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        div.centred_background_stage_1 {
            position: fixed;
            z-index:(-1 );
            top: 45%;
            left: 50%;
        }

        div.centred_background_stage_2 {
            position: relative;
            left: -50%;

            top: -208px;
            /* % does not work.
               According to the
               http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html
               6pt is about 8px

               In the case of this demo the background
               text consists of three lines with
               font size 80pt.

               3 lines (with space between the lines)
               times 80pt is about
               ~3*(1.3)*80pt*(8px/6pt)~ 416px

               50% from the 416px = 208px
             */

            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        #bells_and_wistles_for_the_demo {
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 80pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #E0E0E0;
        }

        div.centred_background_foreground {
            z-index: 1;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="centred_background_stage_1">
    <div class="centred_background_stage_2">
        <div id="bells_and_wistles_for_the_demo">
            World<br/>
            Wide<br/>
            Web
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="centred_background_foreground">
    This is a demo for <br/>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/center-element-with-positionfixed">
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/center-element-with-positionfixed
    </a>
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="http://www.starwreck.com/" style="border: 0px;">
        <img src="./star_wreck_in_the_perkinnintg.jpg"
             style="opacity:0.1;"/>
    </a>
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does seem to work, although it requires you to already know the width and height of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for horizontal elements that won't center correctly.

width: calc (width: 100% - **width whatever else is off centering it**)

For example if your side navigation bar is 200px:

```
width: calc(100% - 200px);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works wonderfully when you don't know the size of the thing you are centering, and you want it centered in all screen sizes:

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 5%;           /* (100 - height) / 2 */
  left: 5%;          /* (100 - width) / 2 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I use is simple. For example I have a nav bar that is `position : fixed` so I adjust it to leave a small space to the edges like this.

```
nav {
right: 1%;
width: 98%;
position: fixed;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
}
```

The idea is to take the remainder percentage of the width "in this case 2%" and use the half of it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem so I concluded that using a (invisible) container is the best option (based on answer @Romulus Urakagi Ts'ai). To make it with flexbox:

```
.zoom-alert {
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 24px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  width: 100%;

  &__alert {
    flex: 0 0 500px;
    padding: 24px;
    background-color: rgba(212, 193, 105, 0.9);
    border: 1px solid rgb(80, 87, 23);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

(the syntax is SCSS but can be easily modified to pure CSS)

[image: fixed centered alert]

Answer (score 0):

#### Center element of a div with the property of

`position:fixed`

**Html and Css code**

```css
.jqbox_innerhtml {
   position: fixed;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="jqbox_innerhtml">
    This should be inside a horizontally
    and vertically centered box.
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Another simple solution is to set the `width` of the element to `fit-content` and set the `left` and `right` to `0px`;

```css
width: fit-content;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
```

This is useful if you don't know the width of the element.

Answer (score -15):

The only foolproof solution is to use table align=center as in:

```
<table align=center><tr><td>
<div>
...
</div>
</td></tr></table>
```

I cannot believe people all over the world wasting these copious amount to silly time to solve such a fundamental problem as centering a div. css solution does not work for all browsers, jquery solution is a software computational solution and is not an option for other reasons.

I have wasted too much time repeatedly to avoid using table, but experience tell me to stop fighting it. Use table for centering div. Works all the time in all browsers! Never worry any more.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.  There's no non-CSS equivalent to `position:fixed`.