# How do I align a div in CSS?

Tags: css, html, xhtml

I have a box that I made in CSS and I want it to be aligned to the center. Unfortunately I have looked all over and cannot find an answer that works.
HTML:

```
<div id="top_bar">
        <div class="inner">

        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top_bar {
vertical-align:text-top;
width: 90%;
/*padding: 10px;*/
border: 3px solid gray;
/*margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;*/
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}

#top_bar .inner {
  padding:10px;
}

body { margin-left:0px; }
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It just makes my bar not be stuck at the bottom(I am moving it to the top after).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove 
`position:fixed`,
see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/margin-to-center-with-position-fixed) for more info

Answer (score 1):

```
#top_bar{
  margin:0 auto;
  /* Others .... */
}
```

Comment: The block should have fixed with to use that.

Comment: If position is needed to be fixed and width = 90%, just set left:5%;

Comment: Oh, I actually oversaw `width=90%` in OP's CSS, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting margin: auto on the inner div

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/Nm2sD/2/).

If a parent element like #wrapper in this case has `text-align:center` and the #content container inside has `margin: 0 auto;`, it'll center. You can play with this jsFiddle to get a feel for what different rules will do, and apply what you learn to your code above.

In your code above, `position: fixed` is forcing the container to a position. It'll need to be removed for centering to work as I've shown in my sample.