# Why isn't this div centerd on screen?

Tags: html, css

After I did some changes, my feedback div no longer centers on screen and I can't figure out why.

To center a element one only have to set the width and then just do `margin: 0 auto`; That should normally be enough.

The goal is to have the div shown at the top of the screen, centered. You can see my fiddel here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3u3fd/

Code:

```
#feedback {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 300px;    
  margin: 10px auto;
  z-index: 9000;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 24px;
  border: solid 1px #d1d2d1;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f7f2e7;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;  
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* FF < 4.0 */
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;     /* Rounded corners for Safari */ 
}

#feedback span { display: block; float: left;}
#feedback #feedback_icon { width: 24px; height: 24px; overflow: hidden; margin-right: 10px; }
#feedback #feedback_text { height: 24px; line-height: 24px; display: inline-block; }


​
<div class="clearfix" id="feedback" style="display: block;"><span class="dialogFail" id="feedback_icon"></span><div class="" id="feedback_text">Message here</div></div>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Because of `position: fixed;`.

Comment: take a look at this link as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/margin-to-center-with-position-fixed

Comment: Also, `border-radius` should probably be after the prefixed versions.

Comment: The DIV is in the footer and is available on all pages needing to show feedback. It's must show on top of all elements, on top of screen (even if you scroll) and centered.

Comment: Also, it must be a pretty complex site if you have 9000 different display layers...

Comment: No really, I just wanna make sure it show on top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto` margins do not work on elements with `position: fixed`.

Instead, you need to do this:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -Xpx;
width: Ypx;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Where `X = Y/2`.

(The `box-sizing: border-box` ensures that even if you have padding or borders, it will still be centred. If that interferes with the desired width, then remove it and subtract the value of `padding-left + border-left-width` from the `margin-left`.)

Comment: @DavidBélanger: What on Earth is position: float;?

Answer (score 1):

You have a fixed position set.  Get rid of it and it will center just fine.

Comment: Nope, that will not work. The div should be displayed at the top of the screen, end remain there even if you are scrolling. The DIV is located in the footer.

Comment: @Steven That is not what your original post says.  You asked why your div wasn't centered and I explained why.  Your later comment adding your "sticky" requirement came after my answer.

Comment: My original post says: `The goal is to have the div shown at the top of the screen, centered.` @Kolink understood the context and provided correct answer. Thanks trying though :)

Comment: Again, your original post said nothing about having it remain there after scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `margin: 0 auto;` to work, the parent element **must** have a specified width. It can be percentage or units, but it must have it.

For this solution to work in this case, you need to remove the position: fixed; and top declaraions and add a wrapping element.

http://jsfiddle.net/3u3fd/16/