# Jquery CSS How To Use Margin: 0 auto

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to Jquery. I want to know how can we use margin: 0 auto; CSS code in jquery scripting. Could anyone please help me out? Here's the code:

```
<style>
#fixed-bar {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
}
</style>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(function () {
  $("#fixed-bar")
    .css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "width": "960px",
        "margin": "0 auto",
        "top": "0px",

})
    .hide();
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
      $('#fixed-bar').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
      $('#fixed-bar').fadeOut(200);
    }
  });
});
</script>
<div id='fixed-bar'>
  Hello
</div>
```

Actually I want to center the bar. How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to style the bar with jQuery? If at all possible, you should keep your styles in CSS.

Comment: You want to center the bar horizontally or veritcally?

Comment: I'm not able to center the bar. Can you please post the working code, either with CSS or style the bar with jquery? I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It's time for you to evaluate the differences between just setting your style with CSS and using jQuery/JavaScript to over-ride a CSS style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting everything correct.
But you cannot center an element with `margin: auto` that has `position: fixed`:

[Center a position:fixed element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/margin-to-center-with-position-fixed)

You could also do this with jQuery:

[Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

Comment: Thanks Binarious. Yes, we  cannot center an element with margin: auto that has position: fixed:. But adding left:0 and right:0 to it works :) Thanks again. Here're the changes I made to the CSS file above.

[code]#fixed-bar {
      position:fixed;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    left:0;
    right:0;[code]

Answer (score 1):

You can't use shorthand CSS with jQuery, you would have to set each margin separately.

```
css({
    "marginTop": "0",
    "marginRight": "auto",
    "marginBottom": "0",
    "marginLeft": "auto"
})
```

Comment: Not sure why I am getting all the downvotes. According to the jQuery documentation his margins wouldn't get applied (right before the example):http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

**HTML:**

```
<div id="fixed-bar">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    position : relative;
}

#fixed-bar {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 960px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#fixed-bar").css({
                "position" : "absolute",
                "left" : (($(window).width() - $("#fixed-bar").outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px" })
               .hide();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $('#fixed-bar').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        $('#fixed-bar').fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

This way your element will be horizontally centered regardless of screen size. Don't forget to include jQuery in your HTML.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Thanks anyways @Husar. I have figured out what I was doing wrong. Here is the working code :) 

<pre>
<style>
#fixed-bar {
      position:fixed;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
</style>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(function () {
  $("#fixed-bar")
    .css({
        
        "width": "960px",
         "bottom": "0px",
        
})
    .hide();
. . . . . 

</pre>

Comment: I have edited my answer. It definitely works now. This way your element will be horizontally centered regardless of screen size and element width.

Answer (score -2):

There are better ways to center a div using jQuery, such as setting it to absolute position and finding its width, the viewports width, and setting the offset based on those numbers:

```
$('.mydiv').css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
```

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` will work without it's parent having text-align:center. The element in question just needs to have a declared width is all.

Comment: Yes, right, sorry I missed that. I still would use a jQuery solution though.

Comment: Please explain why you'd use a jQuery solution in place of a simple CSS solution?

Comment: It was my assumption that he needs to use jQuery, for whatever reason, since he didn't simply set the margin in CSS. Maybe I was over thinking it, but I got the impression that a javascript solution was a requirement. Maybe my previous comment should have said "I would still use this as a jQuery solution if that is a requirement"