# img behaving like a background img?

Tags: html, css

I have a physical image on a page..

```
<img src="image.png" alt="image-name" />
```

I want it to behave as if it was the body background image though..

```
body{
background: url(image.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

i.e centered without the browser seeing it, so no scroll bars if its wider the the browser etc?

Is this possible?

Comment: is the image always centered?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, you'll probably have to do something like this :

CSS

```
#your-image {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <img id="your-image src="" alt="">
    <div id="container">
        <!-- All your content goes there -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you change "z-index:1" to "z-index:-5000", it really works!:) thank you!:)

Answer (score 1):

Is `position: fixed; z-index: -5000` what you want?

`position: fixed` make the image always fixed on a certain position on the browser regardless of the content.

`z-index: -5000` just put the image behind everything

To make it centered I think you need to know the size of image beforehand. If you do, add

```
top: 50%; 
left: 50%;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: -250px;
```

Where 100 is half your image's height, and 250 is half your image's width. Taken from  [Center a position:fixed element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/margin-to-center-with-position-fixed)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SPsRd/1/

Answer (score 0):

The right way to use it is:

```
  body { background-image:url(image.png) no-repeat center top;}
```