# centering a menu

Tags: css, list, centering

I don't understand why my menu is not centering. I tried everything from inline elements to margin: 0 auto; to align="center" and I can not get the menu to center. You can see it here http://jeremyspence.net78.net you have to scroll down all the way to see it, t only appears when it goes past the main menu. Here is some css

```
.scrollmenu {
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1020px;
    z-index: 10000;
    padding:0;
}
.scrollmenu li{
    width: 200px;
    height: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin-right: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.scrollmenu li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.scrollmenu li a{
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
}
.scroll-icon{
    font-family: 'Symbols';
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333;
    line-height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.scroll-home{
    font-size: 30px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 30%;
}
.scrollmenu li:nth-child(2):hover{
    background-color: #CEFECE;
}
.scrollmenu li:nth-child(3):hover{
    background-color: #CEFEFE;
}
.scrollmenu li:nth-child(4):hover{
    background-color: #CECEFE;
}
.scrollmenu li:last-child:hover{
    background-color: #FECEFE;
}
```

Comment: Btw, I answerd your question so that others that find it have the answer right away but you could have checked this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/margin-to-center-with-position-fixed (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this on your `<ul class="scrollmenu"></ul>` :

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -510px;
```

or :

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're centering a div? `<div>` is a block element, by default. They're centered by using margins. You were close -- you need to make both the left AND right margin auto. `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;`. That will center it inside its parent element, which needs to be 100% width (block elements will expand to maximum width of parent by default). If it's an inline element, you can use `text-align:center;` on its parent (parent still needs to be 100% width), and that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML for your link, it looks like you need to set the `position:fixed` in the `div` above the `ul` menu. It looks like you're setting both `position:fixed` and trying to center at the same time. Get the parent div positioned in the fixed location, and then its child `ul` should be able to be centered via `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving a width to the content div?

```
.content {
position: relative;
width: 1024px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

That seems to solve the issue in Chrome.

By setting `position: fixed;` without a size for the enclosing container, the menu uses the window border for the container, then with all the items floating left... well they all are on the left.