# Recreating Chrome iOS scrolling navigation bar effect in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, header

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect to the way the iOS Chromes navigation bar scrolls and hides, the comes back into view when scrolling up.

This [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edwardomni/xh26X/) is where I am so far.

```
var pos = $(window).scrollTop(),
header = $("header");

$(window).scroll(function () {
var newPos = $(this).scrollTop();

if (newPos > pos) { //down 
    header.css('top', -(newPos) + 'px');
    if (pos > 40) {
        header.css('top', '-40px');
    }
} else { //up
    header.css('top', '0');
}


pos = newPos;

$(".last span").html(pos);
$(".new span").html(newPos);
});
```

So the header scrolls up as you scroll down, but I can't work out how to scroll it back into view in the way I want. Tried using animate() which gave me a scroll in and out, but the animation wasn't smooth. I' want the header to move at the same speed as as the scroll, any ideas?

Comment: Anyone? Perhaps my method is wrong (I'm not too hot with jQuery) so any assistance would be a great help.

Comment: similar question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713389/how-to-hide-show-nav-bar-when-user-scrolls-up-down that works by using jQuery slideDown & slideUP. How can i control the animation rate to match the user scroll speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a similar problem to achive the same effect, maybe this could help you: [Slide header up if you scroll down and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604022/slide-header-up-if-you-scroll-down-and-vice-versa). It would be great to get see some *"nerdy"* people who can get this to work?!

To make it as you noted (the animating way), you could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yckart/jzRfv/

However, I think it would be much nicer to get [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604022/slide-header-up-if-you-scroll-down-and-vice-versa) working!

**CSS**

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 128px;
    background: tomato;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s
}
```

**JS**

```
// something simple to get the current scroll direction
// false === down | true === up
var scrollDir = (function (oldOffset) {
    return function (offset) {
        var dir = offset < oldOffset;
        oldOffset = offset;
        return dir;
    };
}());


var header = document.querySelector('header');
addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    var scrollY = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    header.style.top = -(scrollDir(scrollY) ? 0 : header.clientHeight/2) + 'px';
});
```