# CSS help: Navigation bar position: fixed; I also need to center

Tags: html, css

Class project:

Trying to "anchor" my navigation bar so it stays at the top of the screen.

HTML

```
<nav><a href="index.html"><img src="images/home.jpg" alt="Home" width="120"
height="60" title="Home"></a> <a href="services.html"><img            src="images/services.jpg" alt="Services" width="120"
height="60" title="Services"></a> <a href="training.html"><img    src="images/training.jpg" alt="Training" width="120"
 height="60" title="Training"></a> <a href="about.html"><img      src="images/about.jpg" alt="About" width="120"
height="60" title="About"></a> <a href="media.html"><img src="images/media.jpg" alt="Media" width="120"
height="60" title="Media"></a> <a href="faq.html"><img src="images/faq.jpg"       alt="F.A.Q." width="120"
height="60" title="FAQ"></a> <a href="contact.html"><img   src="images/contact.jpg" alt="Contact" width="120"
height="60" title="Contact"></a></nav>
```

CSS
    nav{
    position:fixed; 
}

*I would post a screen shot by this is my first post and dont have the rep.*

Comment: Please post code demonstrating the problem

Comment: nav{
 position:fixed; 
}

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/center-element-with-positionfixed

Comment: Please post html and css (a working example of the problem) if you need help with this problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/a39toehs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `display:inline-block` and `text-align:center` to make the fixed positioned `nav` centered.

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/28oube50/1/)

HTML

```
<nav>
    <div> 
        <a href="#">HTML</a>
        <a href="#">CSS</a>  
        <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        <a href="#">jQuery</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and the CSS

```
nav a {
    float:left;
}
nav {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
nav div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Great..:)...do your projects well..best wishes...and please dont forget to mark the answer as accepted, if it helped you..