# Fixed Menu Position

Tags: css, menu, position

I want centered fixed menu.I use CSS methods such as : text-align: center; margin (0 auto); but my menu is still on the left. I couldn't figure out where the problem is. Please take a look my example on below.

```css
.topFixedMenu {position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; background: url(http://www.a-zcleaning-removals.co.uk/images/top.gif) repeat-x top; width: 100%; z-index: 400; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center;}
.topFixedMenu a:link, .topFixedMenu a:visited {  text-decoration: none; }
.topFixedMenu a:hover { text-decoration: underline }
.topFixedMenu .logo { margin:3px; background: url(../images/ep_logo.png) no-repeat 0 4px; width: 90px; height:62px; padding-top: 4px; display: inline-block; text-indent: -9999px; float: left; }
.topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav {float: left; list-style-type: none; font:bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:12px auto; padding: 0; }
.topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav li {  float: left; list-style-type: none; }
.topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav li a:link, .topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav li a:visited {  color: #b6b6b6; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none; border-left: 1px solid #6f6f6f; padding: 0 7px; }
.topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav li a:hover { text-decoration: underline }
.container{width: 70%; margin: 60px auto; border-style: solid; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 1px; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topFixedMenu">
 
 <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>

 <ul class="tfmNav">
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link6</a></li>
 </ul>

 
</div>
<div class="container">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam vehicula cursus, vestibulum dignissim ut aliquam, sed mi. Quo dolor mauris, amet fusce cras wisi elementum proin, aliquam amet sit maecenas potenti. Sodales dictum augue sequi ipsum, fermentum enim wisi ridiculus pede massa, blandit donec molestie et, cras tincidunt eget dapibus lobortis maecenas faucibus. Ullamcorper eget faucibus aliquam cursus, phasellus vivamus, risus parturient, vitae eget vulputate ornare molestie pharetra. Elit montes justo, commodo mauris vestibulum donec a congue a, mollis dolor feugiat inventore elementum congue aliquam, suscipit nam pellentesque sit nonummy ac cras, enim varius cursus mauris.
In fringilla rhoncus. Vulputate massa non viverra, laoreet accumsan, volutpat suspendisse wisi pede sollicitudin aliquam, dapibus massa ligula. Etiam sed adipiscing, amet sem, volutpat quis mollis a ac facilisi ornare, ligula sed egestas mauris, viverra imperdiet amet gravida eum accumsan lorem. Aliquip sem maecenas facilisis nec aliquam, nulla sed, et commodo ut ut ac nam, eros ultricies et. Sit pulvinar, sapien luctus, nibh leo. Wisi esse ac justo, ut felis sagittis eleifend fusce, nostra elit enim duis, orci class, donec arcu. Vivamus aliquam mauris elit ut quisque risus, penatibus ante tortor cursus sed lectus, sed non hic eget quis. Nullam risus id diam mauris felis, enim commodo consectetuer. Orci nonummy, magna dis a vestibulum. Ut eget feugiat non imperdiet nulla elit, mi nec elit quis, id sapien, nulla porttitor. At ac ipsum dolore massa aliquam lectus.
Quisque sem tellus viverra augue suspendisse. At in, tincidunt vitae. Sem sapien odio metus lacus, etiam pede ac, vitae pede velit sed ut habitant, velit justo eu ultrices libero mi, sit nec sagittis in semper magna cum. At fusce, dictum varius parturient a, aliquam quam fusce, sed molestie dolor auctor elit justo auctor. Nec mauris leo, venenatis sociosqu nibh enim elit nulla porttitor, velit venenatis, wisi in, est nulla odio velit. Tincidunt aliquet pulvinar nonummy lacinia, quis ante malesuada nec eu et, orci curabitur nullam aliquet vestibulum ligula donec, platea nec etiam adipiscing, vel quam et. Eget excepturi tellus, diam commodo tincidunt ut ipsum lectus metus, vestibulum massa ac felis dui arcu amet. Cursus amet viverra, convallis et ipsum diamlorem sed molestie justo, urna augue vitae.
Tellus lacus sollicitudin dapibus amet sed aliquet, pretium porta hendrerit sit consectetuer, massa nulla in mi convallis, sem in. Etiam ante, nunc hymenaeos amet amet libero leo, ante lobortis vestibulum suspendisse dui erat, eu pede orci tellus massa, in suscipit vel ultricies nec. Ornare ut, purus nulla amet massa facilisis nec, ultricies purus libero aenean duis commodo praesent, tincidunt enim pellentesque erat, cubilia elit nec qui metus lectus. Sed dictum consequat dui. Ornare ipsum mi. Convallis sit praesent, urna nullam orci volutpat, eu posuere nulla aliquam, ac rutrum libero iusto pellentesque metus, vitae vehicula platea mauris in. Mauris in, ante a turpis fermentum ut, malesuada vivamus, praesent neque amet vestibulum adipiscing, sed nibh autem etiam. Integer feugiat vestibulum volutpat. Augue augue accumsan fames mollis est, scelerisque a ligula, tellus ut, felis euismod consequat non, donec suspendisse massa. In nec aliquip, nec condimentum porta non magna nulla.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam vehicula cursus, vestibulum dignissim ut aliquam, sed mi. Quo dolor mauris, amet fusce cras wisi elementum proin, aliquam amet sit maecenas potenti. Sodales dictum augue sequi ipsum, fermentum enim wisi ridiculus pede massa, blandit donec molestie et, cras tincidunt eget dapibus lobortis maecenas faucibus. Ullamcorper eget faucibus aliquam cursus, phasellus vivamus, risus parturient, vitae eget vulputate ornare molestie pharetra. Elit montes justo, commodo mauris vestibulum donec a congue a, mollis dolor feugiat inventore elementum congue aliquam, suscipit nam pellentesque sit nonummy ac cras, enim varius cursus mauris.
In fringilla rhoncus. Vulputate massa non viverra, laoreet accumsan, volutpat suspendisse wisi pede sollicitudin aliquam, dapibus massa ligula. Etiam sed adipiscing, amet sem, volutpat quis mollis a ac facilisi ornare, ligula sed egestas mauris, viverra imperdiet amet gravida eum accumsan lorem. Aliquip sem maecenas facilisis nec aliquam, nulla sed, et commodo ut ut ac nam, eros ultricies et. Sit pulvinar, sapien luctus, nibh leo. Wisi esse ac justo, ut felis sagittis eleifend fusce, nostra elit enim duis, orci class, donec arcu. Vivamus aliquam mauris elit ut quisque risus, penatibus ante tortor cursus sed lectus, sed non hic eget quis. Nullam risus id diam mauris felis, enim commodo consectetuer. Orci nonummy, magna dis a vestibulum. Ut eget feugiat non imperdiet nulla elit, mi nec elit quis, id sapien, nulla porttitor. At ac ipsum dolore massa aliquam lectus.
Quisque sem tellus viverra augue suspendisse. At in, tincidunt vitae. Sem sapien odio metus lacus, etiam pede ac, vitae pede velit sed ut habitant, velit justo eu ultrices libero mi, sit nec sagittis in semper magna cum. At fusce, dictum varius parturient a, aliquam quam fusce, sed molestie dolor auctor elit justo auctor. Nec mauris leo, venenatis sociosqu nibh enim elit nulla porttitor, velit venenatis, wisi in, est nulla odio velit. Tincidunt aliquet pulvinar nonummy lacinia, quis ante malesuada nec eu et, orci curabitur nullam aliquet vestibulum ligula donec, platea nec etiam adipiscing, vel quam et. Eget excepturi tellus, diam commodo tincidunt ut ipsum lectus metus, vestibulum massa ac felis dui arcu amet. Cursus amet viverra, convallis et ipsum diamlorem sed molestie justo, urna augue vitae.
Tellus lacus sollicitudin dapibus amet sed aliquet, pretium porta hendrerit sit consectetuer, massa nulla in mi convallis, sem in. Etiam ante, nunc hymenaeos amet amet libero leo, ante lobortis vestibulum suspendisse dui erat, eu pede orci tellus massa, in suscipit vel ultricies nec. Ornare ut, purus nulla amet massa facilisis nec, ultricies purus libero aenean duis commodo praesent, tincidunt enim pellentesque erat, cubilia elit nec qui metus lectus. Sed dictum consequat dui. Ornare ipsum mi. Convallis sit praesent, urna nullam orci volutpat, eu posuere nulla aliquam, ac rutrum libero iusto pellentesque metus, vitae vehicula platea mauris in. Mauris in, ante a turpis fermentum ut, malesuada vivamus, praesent neque amet vestibulum adipiscing, sed nibh autem etiam. Integer feugiat vestibulum volutpat. Augue augue accumsan fames mollis est, scelerisque a ligula, tellus ut, felis euismod consequat non, donec suspendisse massa. In nec aliquip, nec condimentum porta non magna nulla.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam vehicula cursus, vestibulum dignissim ut aliquam, sed mi. Quo dolor mauris, amet fusce cras wisi elementum proin, aliquam amet sit maecenas potenti. Sodales dictum augue sequi ipsum, fermentum enim wisi ridiculus pede massa, blandit donec molestie et, cras tincidunt eget dapibus lobortis maecenas faucibus. Ullamcorper eget faucibus aliquam cursus, phasellus vivamus, risus parturient, vitae eget vulputate ornare molestie pharetra. Elit montes justo, commodo mauris vestibulum donec a congue a, mollis dolor feugiat inventore elementum congue aliquam, suscipit nam pellentesque sit nonummy ac cras, enim varius cursus mauris.
In fringilla rhoncus. Vulputate massa non viverra, laoreet accumsan, volutpat suspendisse wisi pede sollicitudin aliquam, dapibus massa ligula. Etiam sed adipiscing, amet sem, volutpat quis mollis a ac facilisi ornare, ligula sed egestas mauris, viverra imperdiet amet gravida eum accumsan lorem. Aliquip sem maecenas facilisis nec aliquam, nulla sed, et commodo ut ut ac nam, eros ultricies et. Sit pulvinar, sapien luctus, nibh leo. Wisi esse ac justo, ut felis sagittis eleifend fusce, nostra elit enim duis, orci class, donec arcu. Vivamus aliquam mauris elit ut quisque risus, penatibus ante tortor cursus sed lectus, sed non hic eget quis. Nullam risus id diam mauris felis, enim commodo consectetuer. Orci nonummy, magna dis a vestibulum. Ut eget feugiat non imperdiet nulla elit, mi nec elit quis, id sapien, nulla porttitor. At ac ipsum dolore massa aliquam lectus.
Quisque sem tellus viverra augue suspendisse. At in, tincidunt vitae. Sem sapien odio metus lacus, etiam pede ac, vitae pede velit sed ut habitant, velit justo eu ultrices libero mi, sit nec sagittis in semper magna cum. At fusce, dictum varius parturient a, aliquam quam fusce, sed molestie dolor auctor elit justo auctor. Nec mauris leo, venenatis sociosqu nibh enim elit nulla porttitor, velit venenatis, wisi in, est nulla odio velit. Tincidunt aliquet pulvinar nonummy lacinia, quis ante malesuada nec eu et, orci curabitur nullam aliquet vestibulum ligula donec, platea nec etiam adipiscing, vel quam et. Eget excepturi tellus, diam commodo tincidunt ut ipsum lectus metus, vestibulum massa ac felis dui arcu amet. Cursus amet viverra, convallis et ipsum diamlorem sed molestie justo, urna augue vitae.
Tellus lacus sollicitudin dapibus amet sed aliquet, pretium porta hendrerit sit consectetuer, massa nulla in mi convallis, sem in. Etiam ante, nunc hymenaeos amet amet libero leo, ante lobortis vestibulum suspendisse dui erat, eu pede orci tellus massa, in suscipit vel ultricies nec. Ornare ut, purus nulla amet massa facilisis nec, ultricies purus libero aenean duis commodo praesent, tincidunt enim pellentesque erat, cubilia elit nec qui metus lectus. Sed dictum consequat dui. Ornare ipsum mi. Convallis sit praesent, urna nullam orci volutpat, eu posuere nulla aliquam, ac rutrum libero iusto pellentesque metus, vitae vehicula platea mauris in. Mauris in, ante a turpis fermentum ut, malesuada vivamus, praesent neque amet vestibulum adipiscing, sed nibh autem etiam. Integer feugiat vestibulum volutpat. Augue augue accumsan fames mollis est, scelerisque a ligula, tellus ut, felis euismod consequat non, donec suspendisse massa. In nec aliquip, nec condimentum porta non magna nulla.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam vehicula cursus, vestibulum dignissim ut aliquam, sed mi. Quo dolor mauris, amet fusce cras wisi elementum proin, aliquam amet sit maecenas potenti. Sodales dictum augue sequi ipsum, fermentum enim wisi ridiculus pede massa, blandit donec molestie et, cras tincidunt eget dapibus lobortis maecenas faucibus. Ullamcorper eget faucibus aliquam cursus, phasellus vivamus, risus parturient, vitae eget vulputate ornare molestie pharetra. Elit montes justo, commodo mauris vestibulum donec a congue a, mollis dolor feugiat inventore elementum congue aliquam, suscipit nam pellentesque sit nonummy ac cras, enim varius cursus mauris.
In fringilla rhoncus. Vulputate massa non viverra, laoreet accumsan, volutpat suspendisse wisi pede sollicitudin aliquam, dapibus massa ligula. Etiam sed adipiscing, amet sem, volutpat quis mollis a ac facilisi ornare, ligula sed egestas mauris, viverra imperdiet amet gravida eum accumsan lorem. Aliquip sem maecenas facilisis nec aliquam, nulla sed, et commodo ut ut ac nam, eros ultricies et. Sit pulvinar, sapien luctus, nibh leo. Wisi esse ac justo, ut felis sagittis eleifend fusce, nostra elit enim duis, orci class, donec arcu. Vivamus aliquam mauris elit ut quisque risus, penatibus ante tortor cursus sed lectus, sed non hic eget quis. Nullam risus id diam mauris felis, enim commodo consectetuer. Orci nonummy, magna dis a vestibulum. Ut eget feugiat non imperdiet nulla elit, mi nec elit quis, id sapien, nulla porttitor. At ac ipsum dolore massa aliquam lectus.
Quisque sem tellus viverra augue suspendisse. At in, tincidunt vitae. Sem sapien odio metus lacus, etiam pede ac, vitae pede velit sed ut habitant, velit justo eu ultrices libero mi, sit nec sagittis in semper magna cum. At fusce, dictum varius parturient a, aliquam quam fusce, sed molestie dolor auctor elit justo auctor. Nec mauris leo, venenatis sociosqu nibh enim elit nulla porttitor, velit venenatis, wisi in, est nulla odio velit. Tincidunt aliquet pulvinar nonummy lacinia, quis ante malesuada nec eu et, orci curabitur nullam aliquet vestibulum ligula donec, platea nec etiam adipiscing, vel quam et. Eget excepturi tellus, diam commodo tincidunt ut ipsum lectus metus, vestibulum massa ac felis dui arcu amet. Cursus amet viverra, convallis et ipsum diamlorem sed molestie justo, urna augue vitae.
Tellus lacus sollicitudin dapibus amet sed aliquet, pretium porta hendrerit sit consectetuer, massa nulla in mi convallis, sem in. Etiam ante, nunc hymenaeos amet amet libero leo, ante lobortis vestibulum suspendisse dui erat, eu pede orci tellus massa, in suscipit vel ultricies nec. Ornare ut, purus nulla amet massa facilisis nec, ultricies purus libero aenean duis commodo praesent, tincidunt enim pellentesque erat, cubilia elit nec qui metus lectus. Sed dictum consequat dui. Ornare ipsum mi. Convallis sit praesent, urna nullam orci volutpat, eu posuere nulla aliquam, ac rutrum libero iusto pellentesque metus, vitae vehicula platea mauris in. Mauris in, ante a turpis fermentum ut, malesuada vivamus, praesent neque amet vestibulum adipiscing, sed nibh autem etiam. Integer feugiat vestibulum volutpat. Augue augue accumsan fames mollis est, scelerisque a ligula, tellus ut, felis euismod consequat non, donec suspendisse massa. In nec aliquip, nec condimentum porta non magna nulla.
  

 </p>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center element with position:fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/center-element-with-positionfixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off your logo is in your .`topFixedMenu` which is causing it to not go in the middle but you CSS is everywhere so try this

lets move your logo above one element it wont make a difference.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
<div class="topFixedMenu">
    <ul class="tfmNav">
        <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

now you need to add `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` which will push it to the middle, worked in the browser when i just did it. you need to remove this class below css and paste mine in

```
.topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav {
 list-style-type: none;
 font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin: 12px auto;
 padding: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

here is your snippet corrected by me (i can not be bothered to fix all the code syntax it is just for you to view it)

```css
.topFixedMenu {position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; background: url(http://www.a-zcleaning-removals.co.uk/images/top.gif) repeat-x top; width: 100%; z-index: 400; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center;}
.topFixedMenu a:link, .topFixedMenu a:visited {  text-decoration: none; }
.topFixedMenu a:hover { text-decoration: underline }
.topFixedMenu .logo { margin:3px; background: url(../images/ep_logo.png) no-repeat 0 4px; width: 90px; height:62px; padding-top: 4px; display: inline-block; text-indent: -9999px; float: left; }
.topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav {list-style-type: none;font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin: 12px auto;padding: 0;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;}
.topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav li {  float: left; list-style-type: none; }
.topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav li a:link, .topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav li a:visited {  color: #b6b6b6; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none; border-left: 1px solid #6f6f6f; padding: 0 7px; }
.topFixedMenu ul.tfmNav li a:hover { text-decoration: underline }
.container{width: 70%; margin: 60px auto; border-style: solid; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 1px; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
   
 <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
<div class="topFixedMenu">

 <ul class="tfmNav">
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="Link1">Link6</a></li>
 </ul>

 
</div>
<div class="container">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam vehicula cursus, vestibulum dignissim ut aliquam, sed mi. Quo dolor mauris, amet fusce cras wisi elementum proin, aliquam amet sit maecenas potenti. Sodales dictum augue sequi ipsum, fermentum enim wisi ridiculus pede massa, blandit donec molestie et, cras tincidunt eget dapibus lobortis maecenas faucibus. Ullamcorper eget faucibus aliquam cursus, phasellus vivamus, risus parturient, vitae eget vulputate ornare molestie pharetra. Elit montes justo, commodo mauris vestibulum donec a congue a, mollis dolor feugiat inventore elementum congue aliquam, suscipit nam pellentesque sit nonummy ac cras, enim varius cursus mauris.
In fringilla rhoncus. Vulputate massa non viverra, laoreet accumsan, volutpat suspendisse wisi pede sollicitudin aliquam, dapibus massa ligula. Etiam sed adipiscing, amet sem, volutpat quis mollis a ac facilisi ornare, ligula sed egestas mauris, viverra imperdiet amet gravida eum accumsan lorem. Aliquip sem maecenas facilisis nec aliquam, nulla sed, et commodo ut ut ac nam, eros ultricies et. Sit pulvinar, sapien luctus, nibh leo. Wisi esse ac justo, ut felis sagittis eleifend fusce, nostra elit enim duis, orci class, donec arcu. Vivamus aliquam mauris elit ut quisque risus, penatibus ante tortor cursus sed lectus, sed non hic eget quis. Nullam risus id diam mauris felis, enim commodo consectetuer. Orci nonummy, magna dis a vestibulum. Ut eget feugiat non imperdiet nulla elit, mi nec elit quis, id sapien, nulla porttitor. At ac ipsum dolore massa aliquam lectus.
Quisque sem tellus viverra augue suspendisse. At in, tincidunt vitae. Sem sapien odio metus lacus, etiam pede ac, vitae pede velit sed ut habitant, velit justo eu ultrices libero mi, sit nec sagittis in semper magna cum. At fusce, dictum varius parturient a, aliquam quam fusce, sed molestie dolor auctor elit justo auctor. Nec mauris leo, venenatis sociosqu nibh enim elit nulla porttitor, velit venenatis, wisi in, est nulla odio velit. Tincidunt aliquet pulvinar nonummy lacinia, quis ante malesuada nec eu et, orci curabitur nullam aliquet vestibulum ligula donec, platea nec etiam adipiscing, vel quam et. Eget excepturi tellus, diam commodo tincidunt ut ipsum lectus metus, vestibulum massa ac felis dui arcu amet. Cursus amet viverra, convallis et ipsum diamlorem sed molestie justo, urna augue vitae.
Tellus lacus sollicitudin dapibus amet sed aliquet, pretium porta hendrerit sit consectetuer, massa nulla in mi convallis, sem in. Etiam ante, nunc hymenaeos amet amet libero leo, ante lobortis vestibulum suspendisse dui erat, eu pede orci tellus massa, in suscipit vel ultricies nec. Ornare ut, purus nulla amet massa facilisis nec, ultricies purus libero aenean duis commodo praesent, tincidunt enim pellentesque erat, cubilia elit nec qui metus lectus. Sed dictum consequat dui. Ornare ipsum mi. Convallis sit praesent, urna nullam orci volutpat, eu posuere nulla aliquam, ac rutrum libero iusto pellentesque metus, vitae vehicula platea mauris in. Mauris in, ante a turpis fermentum ut, malesuada vivamus, praesent neque amet vestibulum adipiscing, sed nibh autem etiam. Integer feugiat vestibulum volutpat. Augue augue accumsan fames mollis est, scelerisque a ligula, tellus ut, felis euismod consequat non, donec suspendisse massa. In nec aliquip, nec condimentum porta non magna nulla.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam vehicula cursus, vestibulum dignissim ut aliquam, sed mi. Quo dolor mauris, amet fusce cras wisi elementum proin, aliquam amet sit maecenas potenti. Sodales dictum augue sequi ipsum, fermentum enim wisi ridiculus pede massa, blandit donec molestie et, cras tincidunt eget dapibus lobortis maecenas faucibus. Ullamcorper eget faucibus aliquam cursus, phasellus vivamus, risus parturient, vitae eget vulputate ornare molestie pharetra. Elit montes justo, commodo mauris vestibulum donec a congue a, mollis dolor feugiat inventore elementum congue aliquam, suscipit nam pellentesque sit nonummy ac cras, enim varius cursus mauris.
In fringilla rhoncus. Vulputate massa non viverra, laoreet accumsan, volutpat suspendisse wisi pede sollicitudin aliquam, dapibus massa ligula. Etiam sed adipiscing, amet sem, volutpat quis mollis a ac facilisi ornare, ligula sed egestas mauris, viverra imperdiet amet gravida eum accumsan lorem. Aliquip sem maecenas facilisis nec aliquam, nulla sed, et commodo ut ut ac nam, eros ultricies et. Sit pulvinar, sapien luctus, nibh leo. Wisi esse ac justo, ut felis sagittis eleifend fusce, nostra elit enim duis, orci class, donec arcu. Vivamus aliquam mauris elit ut quisque risus, penatibus ante tortor cursus sed lectus, sed non hic eget quis. Nullam risus id diam mauris felis, enim commodo consectetuer. Orci nonummy, magna dis a vestibulum. Ut eget feugiat non imperdiet nulla elit, mi nec elit quis, id sapien, nulla porttitor. At ac ipsum dolore massa aliquam lectus.
Quisque sem tellus viverra augue suspendisse. At in, tincidunt vitae. Sem sapien odio metus lacus, etiam pede ac, vitae pede velit sed ut habitant, velit justo eu ultrices libero mi, sit nec sagittis in semper magna cum. At fusce, dictum varius parturient a, aliquam quam fusce, sed molestie dolor auctor elit justo auctor. Nec mauris leo, venenatis sociosqu nibh enim elit nulla porttitor, velit venenatis, wisi in, est nulla odio velit. Tincidunt aliquet pulvinar nonummy lacinia, quis ante malesuada nec eu et, orci curabitur nullam aliquet vestibulum ligula donec, platea nec etiam adipiscing, vel quam et. Eget excepturi tellus, diam commodo tincidunt ut ipsum lectus metus, vestibulum massa ac felis dui arcu amet. Cursus amet viverra, convallis et ipsum diamlorem sed molestie justo, urna augue vitae.
Tellus lacus sollicitudin dapibus amet sed aliquet, pretium porta hendrerit sit consectetuer, massa nulla in mi convallis, sem in. Etiam ante, nunc hymenaeos amet amet libero leo, ante lobortis vestibulum suspendisse dui erat, eu pede orci tellus massa, in suscipit vel ultricies nec. Ornare ut, purus nulla amet massa facilisis nec, ultricies purus libero aenean duis commodo praesent, tincidunt enim pellentesque erat, cubilia elit nec qui metus lectus. Sed dictum consequat dui. Ornare ipsum mi. Convallis sit praesent, urna nullam orci volutpat, eu posuere nulla aliquam, ac rutrum libero iusto pellentesque metus, vitae vehicula platea mauris in. Mauris in, ante a turpis fermentum ut, malesuada vivamus, praesent neque amet vestibulum adipiscing, sed nibh autem etiam. Integer feugiat vestibulum volutpat. Augue augue accumsan fames mollis est, scelerisque a ligula, tellus ut, felis euismod consequat non, donec suspendisse massa. In nec aliquip, nec condimentum porta non magna nulla.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam vehicula cursus, vestibulum dignissim ut aliquam, sed mi. Quo dolor mauris, amet fusce cras wisi elementum proin, aliquam amet sit maecenas potenti. Sodales dictum augue sequi ipsum, fermentum enim wisi ridiculus pede massa, blandit donec molestie et, cras tincidunt eget dapibus lobortis maecenas faucibus. Ullamcorper eget faucibus aliquam cursus, phasellus vivamus, risus parturient, vitae eget vulputate ornare molestie pharetra. Elit montes justo, commodo mauris vestibulum donec a congue a, mollis dolor feugiat inventore elementum congue aliquam, suscipit nam pellentesque sit nonummy ac cras, enim varius cursus mauris.
In fringilla rhoncus. Vulputate massa non viverra, laoreet accumsan, volutpat suspendisse wisi pede sollicitudin aliquam, dapibus massa ligula. Etiam sed adipiscing, amet sem, volutpat quis mollis a ac facilisi ornare, ligula sed egestas mauris, viverra imperdiet amet gravida eum accumsan lorem. Aliquip sem maecenas facilisis nec aliquam, nulla sed, et commodo ut ut ac nam, eros ultricies et. Sit pulvinar, sapien luctus, nibh leo. Wisi esse ac justo, ut felis sagittis eleifend fusce, nostra elit enim duis, orci class, donec arcu. Vivamus aliquam mauris elit ut quisque risus, penatibus ante tortor cursus sed lectus, sed non hic eget quis. Nullam risus id diam mauris felis, enim commodo consectetuer. Orci nonummy, magna dis a vestibulum. Ut eget feugiat non imperdiet nulla elit, mi nec elit quis, id sapien, nulla porttitor. At ac ipsum dolore massa aliquam lectus.
Quisque sem tellus viverra augue suspendisse. At in, tincidunt vitae. Sem sapien odio metus lacus, etiam pede ac, vitae pede velit sed ut habitant, velit justo eu ultrices libero mi, sit nec sagittis in semper magna cum. At fusce, dictum varius parturient a, aliquam quam fusce, sed molestie dolor auctor elit justo auctor. Nec mauris leo, venenatis sociosqu nibh enim elit nulla porttitor, velit venenatis, wisi in, est nulla odio velit. Tincidunt aliquet pulvinar nonummy lacinia, quis ante malesuada nec eu et, orci curabitur nullam aliquet vestibulum ligula donec, platea nec etiam adipiscing, vel quam et. Eget excepturi tellus, diam commodo tincidunt ut ipsum lectus metus, vestibulum massa ac felis dui arcu amet. Cursus amet viverra, convallis et ipsum diamlorem sed molestie justo, urna augue vitae.
Tellus lacus sollicitudin dapibus amet sed aliquet, pretium porta hendrerit sit consectetuer, massa nulla in mi convallis, sem in. Etiam ante, nunc hymenaeos amet amet libero leo, ante lobortis vestibulum suspendisse dui erat, eu pede orci tellus massa, in suscipit vel ultricies nec. Ornare ut, purus nulla amet massa facilisis nec, ultricies purus libero aenean duis commodo praesent, tincidunt enim pellentesque erat, cubilia elit nec qui metus lectus. Sed dictum consequat dui. Ornare ipsum mi. Convallis sit praesent, urna nullam orci volutpat, eu posuere nulla aliquam, ac rutrum libero iusto pellentesque metus, vitae vehicula platea mauris in. Mauris in, ante a turpis fermentum ut, malesuada vivamus, praesent neque amet vestibulum adipiscing, sed nibh autem etiam. Integer feugiat vestibulum volutpat. Augue augue accumsan fames mollis est, scelerisque a ligula, tellus ut, felis euismod consequat non, donec suspendisse massa. In nec aliquip, nec condimentum porta non magna nulla.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nullam vehicula cursus, vestibulum dignissim ut aliquam, sed mi. Quo dolor mauris, amet fusce cras wisi elementum proin, aliquam amet sit maecenas potenti. Sodales dictum augue sequi ipsum, fermentum enim wisi ridiculus pede massa, blandit donec molestie et, cras tincidunt eget dapibus lobortis maecenas faucibus. Ullamcorper eget faucibus aliquam cursus, phasellus vivamus, risus parturient, vitae eget vulputate ornare molestie pharetra. Elit montes justo, commodo mauris vestibulum donec a congue a, mollis dolor feugiat inventore elementum congue aliquam, suscipit nam pellentesque sit nonummy ac cras, enim varius cursus mauris.
In fringilla rhoncus. Vulputate massa non viverra, laoreet accumsan, volutpat suspendisse wisi pede sollicitudin aliquam, dapibus massa ligula. Etiam sed adipiscing, amet sem, volutpat quis mollis a ac facilisi ornare, ligula sed egestas mauris, viverra imperdiet amet gravida eum accumsan lorem. Aliquip sem maecenas facilisis nec aliquam, nulla sed, et commodo ut ut ac nam, eros ultricies et. Sit pulvinar, sapien luctus, nibh leo. Wisi esse ac justo, ut felis sagittis eleifend fusce, nostra elit enim duis, orci class, donec arcu. Vivamus aliquam mauris elit ut quisque risus, penatibus ante tortor cursus sed lectus, sed non hic eget quis. Nullam risus id diam mauris felis, enim commodo consectetuer. Orci nonummy, magna dis a vestibulum. Ut eget feugiat non imperdiet nulla elit, mi nec elit quis, id sapien, nulla porttitor. At ac ipsum dolore massa aliquam lectus.
Quisque sem tellus viverra augue suspendisse. At in, tincidunt vitae. Sem sapien odio metus lacus, etiam pede ac, vitae pede velit sed ut habitant, velit justo eu ultrices libero mi, sit nec sagittis in semper magna cum. At fusce, dictum varius parturient a, aliquam quam fusce, sed molestie dolor auctor elit justo auctor. Nec mauris leo, venenatis sociosqu nibh enim elit nulla porttitor, velit venenatis, wisi in, est nulla odio velit. Tincidunt aliquet pulvinar nonummy lacinia, quis ante malesuada nec eu et, orci curabitur nullam aliquet vestibulum ligula donec, platea nec etiam adipiscing, vel quam et. Eget excepturi tellus, diam commodo tincidunt ut ipsum lectus metus, vestibulum massa ac felis dui arcu amet. Cursus amet viverra, convallis et ipsum diamlorem sed molestie justo, urna augue vitae.
Tellus lacus sollicitudin dapibus amet sed aliquet, pretium porta hendrerit sit consectetuer, massa nulla in mi convallis, sem in. Etiam ante, nunc hymenaeos amet amet libero leo, ante lobortis vestibulum suspendisse dui erat, eu pede orci tellus massa, in suscipit vel ultricies nec. Ornare ut, purus nulla amet massa facilisis nec, ultricies purus libero aenean duis commodo praesent, tincidunt enim pellentesque erat, cubilia elit nec qui metus lectus. Sed dictum consequat dui. Ornare ipsum mi. Convallis sit praesent, urna nullam orci volutpat, eu posuere nulla aliquam, ac rutrum libero iusto pellentesque metus, vitae vehicula platea mauris in. Mauris in, ante a turpis fermentum ut, malesuada vivamus, praesent neque amet vestibulum adipiscing, sed nibh autem etiam. Integer feugiat vestibulum volutpat. Augue augue accumsan fames mollis est, scelerisque a ligula, tellus ut, felis euismod consequat non, donec suspendisse massa. In nec aliquip, nec condimentum porta non magna nulla.
  

 </p>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```