# Why does this fixed element not center horizontally?

Tags: css

Here is the CSS:

```
#indicator {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 2px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Whenever I apply it, the content stays hard left, not centered.  I have tried it with block elements (such as `P` and `H1`), and inline elements (such as `span`).

When I check the HTML inspector I can see that the rules are being applied as expected, and none are being overridden.

Comment: you can use left:50%; and margin-left:-75px;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center a position:fixed element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/center-a-positionfixed-element)

Answer (score 1):

By default, margin auto wont work with fixed elements. To make the margin auto value work with fixed elements, add left:0 and right:0 to your CSS values.
Attached a code snippet for your reference.

```css
#indicator {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="indicator">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `margin:auto` only works with `position:relative`.

To make a fixed div to work with `margin:auto`, add `left: 0; right:0;` to your div.

```css
#indicator_relative {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #0f0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

#indicator_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f00;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

#indicator_fixed_centered {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #00f;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id='indicator_fixed'></div>
<div id='indicator_relative'></div>
<div id='indicator_fixed_centered'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To center fixed/absolute position elements. Add **left: 50%; margin-left: (element width/ 2 * -1)px;**

```
#indicator {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 2px;
  background: #fff;

  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px; /* (element width / 2 * -1) */
}
```

plus make sure that the parent element where you want to center this, has **position: relative;** so it wont just fly around.

Answer (score -1):

top 40%; horizontal center;

```css
#indicator {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="indicator">Hello World</div>
```

or center screen

```css
#indicator {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="indicator">Hello World</div>
```