# How do I center a <div> that has that has position: fixed without changing display?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the following css code:

```
.popup{
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  animation-name: popup;
  animation-duration: 0.15s;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #cf5c36;
}
```

And I can't figure out how to center it. All the advice I can find involves changing the display, or doesn't work with `display: none;`. Does anyone know how I could go about it it?

Comment: Why bother center a `display: none;` element? It's not visible right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center a position:fixed element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/center-a-positionfixed-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the absolute position and transform it to center

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```