# How to get the 'height' of the screen using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set something in the middle of the screen

thanks

Comment: By "screen" do you mean the browser window? Or literally the screen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/what-is-the-best-way-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen-using-jquery

Answer (score 175, accepted):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

As documented here: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Honestly, this does not answer OP's question. If you are looking for the _actual_ screen height, use
`screen.height` like `var height = screen.height`. This might look like a bug bite, but OP asked how to position something in the middle of the screen, not the middle of the browser window.

Comment: Perfect John White, just what I needed, screen.height worked for me

Comment: John's answer should be the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 5):

use with responsive website (view in mobile or ipad)

```
jQuery(window).height();   // return height of browser viewport
jQuery(window).width();    // return width of browser viewport
```

rarely use

```
jQuery(document).height(); // return height of HTML document
jQuery(document).width();  // return width of HTML document
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).height();
```

To set anything in the middle you can use CSS.

```
<style>
#divCentre 
{ 
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
</style>
<div id="divCentre">I am at the centre</div>
```

Comment: That CSS will put the top left corner of the div in the middle of the page. The div will then extend right and down, looking *seriously* off-center. Maybe make the margins negative? Because that seems like it might work, but only if the thing you're centering is smaller than the page.

Comment: Fixed the typo. Thanks @ T J Crowder

Comment: Your vertical centering approach requires that you know the height of your #divCentre element.