# Show div when it is 20% away from the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, pixel

Heyo,

so I was wondering if it is possible to show the fade-effect of a div, if it is 20% away from the bottom within the currend screen view. So for example if you scroll down on a page and the following contentbox gets a distance of 20% of the screen-height to the bottom of the screen, the fade-in effect runs.

I want this because of the responsive function. I don't want to write a new pixel height for the fade-effect everytime the Screensize changes.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
function Scroll(){
var top = document.getElementById('div1');
var ypos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (ypos > 1000){
        top.style.opacity = "1";
    }
    else {
        top.style.opacity = "0";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll",Scroll);
```

Comment: [Check if element is between 30% and 60% of the viewport](//stackoverflow.com/q/29891587) may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if element is between 30% and 60% of the viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891587/check-if-element-is-between-30-and-60-of-the-viewport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into scroll combined with position and height? https://api.jquery.com/scroll/   and https://api.jquery.com/position/ On the scroll you could get the position of the element in question and compare to the window. http://api.jquery.com/height/ and [How to get the 'height' of the screen using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407221/how-to-get-the-height-of-the-screen-using-jquery)  Those should be all the tools you need.

Comment: Thank you for the Links! They helped me out!