# Animate a display inline to block change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a sticky header which changes size when the page is scrolled.
One of the main features  I want to implement is that an image in the header shrinks down and moves to the left.

So far I have the shrinking down working nicely all animated. 
I also have the moving to the left working, but its not animated.

In jQuery I am calling

```
$('#page_header_logo_img').css({
    "padding-left":"20%",
    "display":"inline"
})
```

at one point and then later call

```
$('#page_header_logo_img').css({
    "padding-left":"0",
    "display":"block"
})
```

Which works beautifully for moving it to exactly where I want... only problem is it jumps there.

I have tried incorporating the [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) effect but couldn't get it to work.

[Here is a JSFiddle of what I currently have](https://jsfiddle.net/ka5jj0ay/1/)
All I need is for the movement left and right to be smooth and not instant.

EDIT FOR ANSWER

I accepted the answer that got me closest, and also answered the question I asked.
However it didn't quite get me what I wanted, so thought I would post the final solution here.

I changed the image to be `position: absolute;` and then dynamically set the margin and the left property.

[You can see a working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ka5jj0ay/8/)

Comment: `display` is not a transitionable property. Sorry. Impossible to do.

Comment: Here you are a list of animated properties in CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want animation effect you can use `.animate()` instead of `.css()` but you can use `display` in it because `display` will not work in `.animate()`.

Rest the function would be like this

```
var scrolPos = $(window).scrollTop();
if(scrolPos>100){
  $('#page_header_logo_img').animate({
    paddingLeft:"20%"
  });
} else {
  $('#page_header_logo_img').animate({
    paddingLeft:"0"
  });
};
```

Comment: Will probably accept this as the answer as it gets me the closest, however I change padding to margin but now wont switch back to auto https://jsfiddle.net/ka5jj0ay/6/

Comment: Yeah bt not the perfect solution...its a kind of strange behaviour that auto is not working rest values are working

Comment: i think its because jQuery needs a number, hence the new calculation

Comment: i think you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511036/jquery-animate-margins-to-auto...well thats also a solution and ofcourse learned a thing..

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using CSS transitions.

Adding `transition: padding-left 0.3s ease-in-out;` to the styles of `#page_header_logo_img` gives it an animated transition when moving left.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ka5jj0ay/3/) in your JSFiddle. It is not very polished but you can see how the CSS transition can be used.

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) for more information of CSS transitions.

Answer (score -1):

You are just changing the CSS properties and so there is an jump.

Use the jQuery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method for smooth transition. Change you code as below.

```
$('#page_header_logo_img').animate({
  "padding-left": "20%",
  "display": "inline"
})
```

and

```
$('#page_header_logo_img').animate({
  "padding-left": "0",
  "display": "block"
})
```