# jQuery Animation Failing with Margin-left/right auto

Tags: jquery, css, animation, margins

I am attempting to make the margins on an image both auto. I am doing this by:

```
$('#headerImg').delay(100).animate({
    "margin-left": "auto",
    "margin-right": "auto"
}, 650, function() {
    //not important
});
```

but it does not work. It does however work if I do:

```
$('#headerImg').css({"margin-left":"auto","margin-right":"auto"});
```

My question is, why is it not working? Is there any possible way to get it to work correctly again or would I need to come up with a hacky solution to solve this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Animate Margins to Auto?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511036/jquery-animate-margins-to-auto)

Comment: Please try my answer and let me know, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('#headerImg').delay(100).animate({
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto"
}, 650, function() {
    //not important
});
```