# DIV positioning

Tags: css, button, position

Hey this is my link: http://ilikeyou.tk/409/

I'm trying to position the Next and Previous buttons (< and >) inside of the container `like_box_page`.

I first centered the buttons using the answer here: [Vertical-Align a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975422/vertical-align-a-div)

Whatever I do, the buttons are still out of place.
Is there a way to center them horizontally in the container?

Comment: Can you photoshop a picture of where you want them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wpuld change even HTML structure, but if to play with this HTML ---

Overwrite these 3 classes :

```
.img_spot {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 20px;
    max-width: 333px;
}

.navigation {        
    height: auto;
    left: -5px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 636px;
}

.like_box_page {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
    border: 1px solid #E4E3E3;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #E9E9E9 inset;
    float: left;
    padding: 16px 61px 13px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Do you,  by any chance, know how to make it work in IE too ? It's kind of messed up there..

Answer (score 2):

use firebug plugin for firefox and you'll see that they are very much in the center of your box, the rest is just off :D He is also much bigger then it's parent.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using absolute positioning? set the parent div to `postion:relative` and the links to `position:absolute` and set the `top` property. That may not be perfect, but I think it would work.

Comment: I did (: it's working but not the way I want it to be in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.navigation`, you need to change the `margin` as follows

```
.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px;  //HERE
    top: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You might also want to give the `img` under it some more `margin`.

`<img style="margin-left:40px;"`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

add `margin-top: -25px;` in .navigation to center the navigation in middle of the height, not start from the center.

P.S. margin-top: -25px or (yourCOntainerHeight) / 2 as negative margin, because you have top: 50% which mean that your element will start at 50% of container height and u must compensate with negative margin to be exatcly in middle.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

In your previous css code,just replace margin-left:10px; to margin-left:200px; 
and margin-rigt:10px; to margin-right:200px;