# Align <div> center of screen - most compatible version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the most compatible method to center (horizontal and vertical) align a `<div>` on a screen?

I am currently using CSS with:

```
div.myBlock
{
    position:absolute;

    width:500px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px;

    height:500px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-250px;
}
```

This works fine in modern browsers, but messes up in older chrome's/firefox's etc.

It is for a basic pop-up such as the pop-ups on FaceBook.

Any ideas? Maybe using JS/jQuery can be effective?

Comment: You do not need to use javascript at all. Your solution above should work in all browsers. What version of firefox chrome doesnt it work in? I would like to see this

Comment: I cant remember, but I showed my site to several friends and 2 (different ones) bugged out.

Comment: What version of CSS? It could be you're using something from a newer version of CSS that old Firefox/Chrome browsers don't know what to do with.

Comment: May it be because I only use `<style>` instead of `<style type="text/css">` ?

Comment: worth a try.. but the css you posted in your question will work in all browsers.. even IE6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm using this function to center my stuff's, have been working so far.

the source is from here, not remember from who.

```
    // $(element).center();
    jQuery.fn.center = function () 
    {
        this.css("position","absolute");
        this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
        return this;
    }
```

**edit:**

found:

[using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)