# Centering div with unknown width

Tags: html, css

i have div `<div id="container"></div>` which contains all page content including header footer etc.

So i would like to center this div to the center of my page, now i have this css:

```
#page{
position:relative;
margin:auto;
width:1000px;
}
```

And it works, but my problem is that content in this div keeps changing so the width changes too, it can be `1000px` or `10100px` so i need something like `width:auto;`, how can do something like that?

Comment: do you mean : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen ?

Comment: @Michael I don't think he's having trouble with centering (confusing title in this case).  If you read the question, he's having trouble with the width of the content.

Comment: Are you asking how to horizontally center an element with an unknown width?

Comment: is the div called #page or #container?

Comment: yes i can center it without any problem but for that i need to use width:some with px; and if my content width get bigger or smaller than my container with some page elements gets messed up

Comment: @SnakeEyes Your link points to how to center a div using jQuery.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/rjY7F/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    i'm as wide as my content
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    /* for ie6/7: */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: I just edited your jsfiddle and removed all styling for `#container` and it still works. I guess the `text-align` on `body` does the trick? Tested in firefox.

Comment: @CodePoet: Doing that means `#container` is now simply full width and the text inside it is centered. [Which isn't what we're after.](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/rjY7F/420/)

Answer (score 16):

One way is to create a wrapper around your `#page` element, let's call it `#wrapper`:

```
#wrapper {
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   float: left;
}
#page {
   position: relative;
   left: -50%;
   float: left;
}
```

This will allow the `#page` div to remain a variable width.

Comment: best solution here imo

Answer (score 6):

This will give you a dinamically-sized div that stays at the center of the body and is the smallest size needed to fit the content:

```
body { text-align: center; }
div.container { display: inline-block; text-align: left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#container {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Assuming `<body><div id="container"></div></body>`