# How to center align content in a DIV tag

Tags: css, html

I have two `div` tags:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="content">
          //content
    </div>
</div>
```

the content of the `<div id="content">` is added dynamically so I don't know its width and I can't set `width` and `margin` to it.

How can I center align `<div id="parent">` content?

PS: I don't want to use javascript to do this.

Comment: Yeah, centering stuff with CSS – that’s totally a new question, has _never_ been asked before …

Comment: Centering div with unknown width http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228536/centering-div-with-unknown-width

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
#parent {
   text-align: center;
}

#content {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`text-align`** property.

```
#parent {
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: center-aligning parent won't help as the content div width is not proper

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani check the other post which is using display: inline-block.