# center a div depending screen width

Tags: jquery

i think i'm doing something wrong.
i mean, I'm trying to make a function to center one divs depending screen width.

## cabecera is the div i'm trying to center using left position

my code start through this thinking:

mw ---> minimal width of the div

mg0 --> left margin + right margin ( the same value for both )

```
$(window).width = mg0 + mw = m + m + mw
```

this is my code.

```
function calc_margen() {
  var mw = 1000;
  var mpw = $(window).width();
  var mg0 = mpw - mw;
  var m = mg0 / 2;
  $('#cabecera').left( m );
  $('#pie').left ( m );
};
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to do this with CSS? jQuery isn't even necessary.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
#cabecera {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$('#cabecera').css({width: 1000, margin: '0 auto'});
```

Comment: This is only for centering on the left and right as your question mentioned, if you are looking for center top, have a look at Garrett Vlieger's link in your question.