# Viewport centring on large website

Tags: jquery, css, width, viewport

Im trying to build a horizontal website which is at 16000px at the moment, using this template

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/WebsiteScrolling/

the website has four sections 4000px wide each, I am trying to achieve a div that will be centred in the browsers viewport at each section.

Vertically, 50% works, but horizontally 50% would be 2000px into the page.

does anyone know anything that would work?

---

I have found a script for centring my #verycentre Div on the first page, it isnt 50% of 4000px, its of the browser window and looks great.

The problem I am having now is that I need a centred window div at each section anchor.

as the page scrolls across and hits each section, im trying to achieve a resizeable #verycentre Div for each section.

The code I am using at the moment is posted below and works perfectly for the first centred div in section 1.

I think the problem might be that the function call is made document.ready

and at that time there is only one #verycentred div in the window, but am not 100% sure.

how can I make all of the #verycentred Div's at each anchor point be centred/resieable?

thanks

Comment: why didn't you go for a jquery control instead of working with this horizontal?

Comment: what will be height and width of that div?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a problem to center it via CSS since your width offsets window area so what you could use is a JQuery function that will help you center that div based on window position

Take a look on this post, where they explain how to center a object based on window area display.

[Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

Comment: I found a code for it, but am having problems in making one  centred div in each 'section', only the first page works.

I have posted the code below

Comment: could you provide your code to us then only it will help us to found the exact issue.

Comment: your code is working you just need to add a relative position on your section class so each div with verycentre respects his parent which would be the container (section)

`.section{
    margin:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:4000px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#96F;
    position:relative;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative left margin with set position:relative;

```
div{
 position:relative;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -2000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
function move_div() {
    window_width = $(window).width() ;
    window_height = $(window).height() ;    

    obj_width = $('#verycentre') .width() ;
    obj_height = $('#verycentre') .height() ;

    $('#verycentre').css('top', (window_height / 2) - (obj_height / 2)) .css('left',       (window_width /2) - obj_width / 2);
    }

    move_div() ;

$(window) .resize(function() {
move_div() ;

});

}) ;
</script>
```