# Center a div between another div and the bottom of the window using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, center, vertical-alignment

I have a webpage laid out as follows...

```
|----------------------|
|     |----------|     |
|     | Logo div |     |
|     |----------|     |
|                      |
|     |----------|     |
|     |          |     |     
|     | Content  |     |
|     |          |     |
|     |----------|     |
|----------------------|
```

Currently I'm attempting to center my `div` (`Content`) using the following function:

```
 jQuery.fn.center = function () {
this.css("position","absolute");
this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
return this;
```

}

which I obtained from another SO question: [Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

This function works fine if my resolution is large enough, however on smaller screens it causes the `div` I'm centering to "come up" and share space with a `div` containing a Logo above  it. So what I'd like to achieve with jQuery is to center it vertically in-between the logo `div` `#logo` and the "end" of the page without floating on top of the logo `div`.

How would I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is absolutely positioned you can't really reference it in relation to another div.

What you need to do is check the height/width calculations and if they are outside of the minimum requirements then replace them with a fixed value.  You could hard code the fixed value or use JQuery to get the height of the logo div.

Something along the lines of:

```
var h = 100; //Height of logo div
var top_position = (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop();

if(top_position < h)
    top_position = h;

this.css("top", top_position + "px");
```