# Element to go to center of viewing area

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a light box from scratch in JQuery, it works well, My problem is that when you click what you want to pop up, it pops up on an absolute position on the page, so if you're scrolled all the way to the bottom and click on something, you have to scroll all the way up to see what popped up. Here's my CSS... the element's postion is the class of "outer":

```
.outer{
    display:none; 
    width:770px; 
    height:475px; 
    top:25%; 
    left:17.5%; 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3; 

}
.inner{
    width:750px; 
    height:450px; 
    background-color:white; 
    border:1px solid #000; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #111; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #111; 
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #111; 
    margin-top:15px;
    z-index:4;
}


.exit_button{ 
    float:right;
    z-index:6;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.inner_content{
    display:none;
    z-index:99;
 }
.next{
    cursor: pointer; 
    margin-left:240px; 
}

.previous{
    cursor: pointer; 
    margin-left:275px;
}
```

Here's my JQuery in case this needs to be done in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button1').click(function() {
        var get_id = $(this).attr('id');        
        var current = $('#div_pic_'+get_id);
        current.show();         
        if (current.is(':last-child')) {
            $('.next').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.previous').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else if (current.is(':first-child')) {
            $('.previous').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.next').prop('disabled', false);

        }
        else
        {
            $('.next').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.previous').prop('disabled', false);
        }

        $('.outer').fadeIn(750);        
        $('.button1').unbind('click');

});

$('.exit_button').click(function() {
        $('.button1').bind('click', function() {

        var get_id = $(this).attr('id');        
        var current = $('#div_pic_'+get_id);
        current.show();         
        if (current.is(':last-child')) {
            $('.next').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.previous').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else if (current.is(':first-child')) {
            $('.previous').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.next').prop('disabled', false);

        }
        else
        {
            $('.next').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.previous').prop('disabled', false);
        }

        $('.outer').fadeIn(750);        
        $('.button1').unbind('click');

});

        $('.outer').fadeOut();
        $('.inner_content').hide();

});


$('.next').click(function() {         
        var current1 = $('.inner_content:visible');
        var nextSlide = current1.next('.inner_content');
        if (current1.is(':last-child')) {
            $('.next').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.previous').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
        current1.hide();
        nextSlide.show();
        $('.next').prop('disabled', false);
        $('.previous').prop('disabled', false);
        }
});


$('.previous').click(function() {
        var current2 = $('.inner_content:visible');
        var prevSlide = current2.prev('.inner_content');
        if (current2.is(':first-child')) {
            $('.previous').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.next').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
        current2.hide();
        prevSlide.show();
        $('.next').prop('disabled', false);
        $('.previous').prop('disabled', false);
        }

});





});
```

This is like one of my first JQuery projects so my coding may suck.

and a quick version of my HTML:

```
<img src="whatever.png" id="001" class="button1" />

<div class="outer">
<img src="images/closebox.png" class="exit_button" />
<div class="inner">

<div class="inner_content" id="div_pic_001">
</div>

</div>   
<button class="previous">Prev</button><button class="next">Next</button>    
</div>
```

This all works great, just how would I get it to pop up in the center of the area the user is viewing? I tried to do it in CSS with percentages, but that only works if the page is a static height and doesn't scroll past the top. Any CSS tricks to do this or do I have to add this into my JQuery and how would I go about that?
Thank you
-Mike

Comment: `left: 17.5%` may look centered on your resolution when the element has a width of 750px, but on a really large (or small) resolution it won't. A way to actually center it in the middle of all resolutions is to use `left: 50%` together with `margin-left: -[HALF WIDTH]px`.
Edit: Regarding your problem, simply add the scrollTop value to the top as well, or switch to `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to center the image in the window.

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
  this.css("position","absolute");
  this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
  this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + enter code here$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
  return this;
}
```

Code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

Then:

```
$('.outer').center().fadeIn(750);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, I'm going to try this, I think I see how to do this... something like. 


     jQuery.fn.center = function () {
     var this = $('.outer');
      this.css("position","absolute");
       this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2)    + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
         return this;
           }

Comment: @user1053263 The big chunk of code is going to extend jQuery and add a `center` method. It needs to be included before you try to use it and after the jQuery source is included on the page. Once it is included, you just use it. No need to edit it at all. Use it like this `$(element).center();` I would add it just before `$(document).ready...`