# Grow from center animation with JQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm looking to have a popup div from a button.  When the button is clicked, I want the popup to grow outwards from the center of the button and at the same time, slide to the center of the screen.  I don't think this should be too hard but I can't find any snippets anywhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks to the help from Jamie Dixon, I got this code working.

```
$('#grower').css({
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    border: '10px solid #999',
    height: '0px',
    width: '0px',
    color: '#111111',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    padding: '10px',
    display: 'none',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: $(this).position().left,
    top: $(this).position().top
}).appendTo('#overlay').fadeIn(0).animate({
    position: 'absolute',
    height: '200px',
    width: '600px',
    marginTop: '-120px',
    marginLeft: '-320px',
    display: "",
    top: ((($(parent).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
    left: ((($(parent).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI with the show method passing in "scale" as a parameter.

```
 $('#growwer').show("scale",{}, 1000);
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wNXLY/)

To slide your element to the center o the page I've created a modified version of Tony L's jQuery function found here: [Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen).

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GbDw9/622/)

**Update**

Here's a working example of the two animations running simultaniously:

http://jsfiddle.net/wNXLY/1/

To get this to work I included an extra parameter on the `animate` function passing in: `{duration: durationLength, queue: false}`

Comment: Is there a way to make both animations happen simultaneously?

Comment: I'm just looking into that now. I'll let you know once I've figured it out.

Comment: I think I found it.  Thanks to your functions.  I posted it in the question.

Comment: I've got an demo too, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to scale it only in one axis?