# How do I make a box with Jquery easing expand from centre

Tags: jquery, easing, jquery-easing

Hey guys I'm pretty new here and was wanting to know some jquery info for a university project.

I'm using two jquery scripts:

jquery-1.9.1.min.js
jquery.easing.1.3.js

Here's an example I've done of my current easing
http://opax.swin.edu.au/~9689419/HDMMD211/TASKS/Task3%20site/

What I want is a rectangle to expand and shrink from the centre instead of from the left-hand side.

let me know if any of you guys have found a solution for this, im stuck .

cheers friends

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351431/grow-from-center-animation-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin: auto` for your divs (row1, row2...) in your CSS. That will make them center horizontally. 
If you want to keep top and bottom margins, then set `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`