# center image on hover thumb css

Tags: jquery, css, html, thumbnails, center

I would like to let images popup in the center of the screen, when I hover over a thumb. I have multiple thumbs and I all want them to display a div (which includes text and an image) right in the center of the screen, independent from the screen resolution etc. etc.

```
<a href="#thumb"><img src="img/thump_5.png" width="150px" border="0" /><span><b>some info and image 1</b><br><img src="img/5.png" width="510" height="335" /></span></a>
<br>
<a href="#thumb"><img src="img/thump_2.png" width="150px" border="0" /><span><b>some info and image 2</b><br><img src="img/2.png" width="510" height="335" /></span></a>
<br>
<a href="#thumb"><img src="img/thump_3.png" width="150px" border="0" /><span><b>some info and image 3</b><br><img src="img/3.png" width="510" height="335" /></span></a> 
<br>
<a href="#thumb"><img src="img/thump_4.png" width="150px" border="0" /><span><b>some info and image 4</b><br><img src="img/4.png" width="510" height="335" /></span></a>
<br>
<a href="#thumb"><img src="img/thump_1.png" width="150px" border="0" /><span><b>some info and image 5</b><br><img src="img/1.png" width="510" height="335" /></span></a>
```

I bumped into this question: [Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

But I have no clue how to implement this in my html code.
Can anyone help me out with the css / jquery to get it working.
Regards,

Matthijs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be exactly what you are looking for:

- http://jmar.github.com/jquery-hoverZoom/

These are not exactly centering a div in the middle of the screen but they look good too ;)

- http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/
- http://james.padolsey.com/demos/imgPreview/full/
- http://home.comcast.net/~littlemoe85/thumbhover/index.html

Comment: The first one looks very nice and I think I can use that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it is hard to give you an allaround answer, but in css terms when you have define a div's `width` and `height` attributes to some concrete values (not `auto`) and then do `position:relative; margin: auto;`, then the div should center within it's parent. If you want a more extensive answer do a fiddle of what you already have.

Comment: Although this is not the only way to do this and won't work too well if you have other content within the same parent element

Comment: I indeed have more content in the same parent. So, this will not work. But thanks.