# Div Horizontal Center NO Absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm with a little problem.

I have the container div for some elements which are images, inside other divs.
Something like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="draggable">
        <img src="something">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to center the container verticaly, but i can't use the top: -healfHeight; margin-top: 50%; because then the jquery ui drag won't work. So any other idea of how can i solve this? :(

Comment: calculate the height of the image, the height of the screen and then the top value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen

Comment: Using JS for presentational purposes is wrong.

Comment: why are you saying that jquery  draggable don't work when it's position is absolute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var wh = $(window).height();
var ch = $('#container').height();
var mt = (wh - ch) / 2;
$('#container').css('margin-top', mt)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zJrKh/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the parent container to `position: relative`, and the element you want to center to `margin: auto`.

Comment: +1 That solved my problem, actually I didn't need `position: relative` on parent wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how jquery positioning works, but if your answer involves only position on these divs with CSS, then:

Make the container div
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;

Then your 'draggable' div needs this positioning:
    position:relative;
    top:(-half the total height of the div);
    left:(-half the width of the div);

For examples, if your draggable div is 100px by 100px, then the top would be -50px and the left would be -50px.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="draggable">
        <img src="something">
    </div>
</div>
```

Marke sure the parent width is wider than the draggable element, then try:

```
#draggable{display:block;margin:0 auto}
```

Edit, sorry, just realised you need it centered vertically.

Try:

```
#container{display:table-cell}
#draggable{vertical-align:middle}
```