# Unable to center image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to black out the screen and center an image in the middle of the screen, above all other elements. What I have doesn't work (the image being centered part).

**NOTE** - I know there are probably plugins for this..but I'm trying to figure out how to do it and how it works.

```
var docHeight = $(document).height();

$("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

$("#overlay").height(docHeight).css({
    'opacity': 0.4,
    'position': 'relative',
    'top': 0,
    'left': 0,
    'color': 'white',
    'background-color': 'black',
    'width': '100%',
    'z-index': 5000
});

$("#overlay").append("<div id='image-container'><img id='photo' src='" + $(this).attr('rel') + "' alt='image' /></div>");

$("#image-container").css("position", "absolute");
$("#image-container").css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $("#image-container").outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
$("#image-container").css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $("#image-container").outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
```

CSS:

```css
#image-container {
    background: #FF0000;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

My image that I'm displaying is in the bottom right of the screen..not in the center. What am I doing wrong?

[JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5rRqS/1)

Comment: yes, if that is a big image that's not a good solution, your code centered the image here, http://jsfiddle.net/5rRqS/, what is the problem?

Comment: Look at the updated with an image: this also centers the top left in the middle, not the middle of the image in the middle. http://jsfiddle.net/5rRqS/1/

Comment: look at BlockUI plugin and reverse engineer it. Has been battle tested for years, and put together by well regarded plugin author who's plugins are on many big name sites. A few minutes in spent in Firebug will explain a lot to you

Comment: @DoctorOreo - **Fun fact:** You don't need `+"px"` in `.css()` in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Centering elements vertically is hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9758556/1081234). A trivial workaround would be centering the background of an element covering the screen:

```
#overlay {
    /*Cover the entire screen regardless of scrolling*/
    position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
    background: #ff0000 url(...) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

[Fiddle'd](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/Fm2ub/) with a semitransparent bgcolor for demo purposes

Comment: Perfect. I was trying to also block out the screen using absolute positioning, but due to my other elements it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the overlay fixed positioned with width and height 100percent and a big zindex. Now you have a trnslucent black div that covers the entire window, not entire document as you are trying. As we have this positioned fixed it wont scroll even if you scroll page. Now to center the image use your simple math. One method is to make image positioned absolute with left as 50percent and then marginleft as -(width of image/2) . This is useful if the image width is same for all cases and can be added on css. In that case you just have to fadein and fade out the overlay div with jquery. No codes for now as i am on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/5rRqS/2/ (im not sure about all browsers).

When your script is runnig image have width=0px and height=0 so, if you want use JS, you have to run positioning script after image is loaded, or add image width and height to  (by attributes or styles)

Then use something like

```
$(img).load(function(){
   // positioning script here
})
```

Comment: Your css solution is incorrect since when setting top margins in %, the value is calculated *as a percentage always relative to the **width** of the containing block* https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/margin-top

Comment: is correct - containing block for img is #image-container and it has always the same size like img.

Comment: wrong again, just substitute an image with different dimensions and it becomes obviously uncentered: http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/5rRqS/3/