# Is it bad practice to use minus (-) pixels in CSS for margins?

Tags: css, margin, pixel

```
.cpn .paymentPage .payment-fire .right {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;

  position: relative;
  margin-right: -27px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Is the margin-right: -27px bad practice vs margin-left: 309px;

Comment: negative values for margins are just fine.

Comment: it is perfectly good practice if it is what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do negative margins in CSS work and why is (margin-top:-5 != margin-bottom:5)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495200/how-do-negative-margins-in-css-work-and-why-is-margin-top-5-margin-bottom5)

Comment: A lot of what we do in CSS wouldn't be possible without negative margins/padding - see the above linked answer for more.

Comment: [Link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/) I hope its enough

Answer (score 6):

No, not at all. It's a useful tool that is as valid as having positive margins.

Other properties where you can't have negative values do nothing - e.g. negative padding or font-size, so don't worry, negative margins are fine!