# Remove unwanted padding at bottom of bootstrap static navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and am having trouble with the navbar. In my navbar, I have a few divs that I want to be the full height of the navbar, but the navbar constantly seems to be just a bit taller than the divs inside. I figured this was due to some padding on the navbar somewhere, but I can't find it. Check out this jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2fax4vme/

Note the three `.rhombus` divs. They should be the full height of the navbar, but there is 5 pixels of extra space under them. If I make the rhombus divs 5 pixels taller, the navbar just stretches.

I'm sure this is something simple I'm not missing, but I just can't spot it.

Answer (score 3):

I would not try and edit the bootstrap navbar css. In stead, why dont you just counter the padding by adding a negative margin bottom to your rhombus (and add an extra few pixels to the height)

```
       .rhombus{
            height:50px; /* + 5px */
            width: 35px;
            -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
            -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
            -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
            display: inline-block;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            margin-bottom: -5px; /* counter the padding */
        }
```

and the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2fax4vme/2/

Comment: This does solve my problem, but I'd appreciate it if you could explain what is actually going on here, thanks!

Comment: have a look at this answer for an explanation on negative margins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495200/how-do-negative-margins-in-css-work-and-why-is-margin-top-5-margin-bottom5

Comment: I just don't understand why it needs to be used here. What part of the CSS is causing the navbar to expand when its contents get taller?

Answer (score 1):

What about changing the height of `.rhombus` to `height:50px;`. It works for me.

For HTML5, it's also necessary to add `margin-bottom:-5px` per Pevara.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gcdwdtLu/  That does not work. The navbar becomes 55px tall.

Comment: I posted a version here which works: http://grokify.github.io/examples/so_29189619.html . The .rhombus divs become taller without stretching the navbar. Could something else be the issue?

Comment: Do you know why it works in your link there, but not the jsFiddle? The code looks the same. I have tried setting `height:50px` in my page and I get the same effect as in the jsFiddle, the navbar just expands.

Comment: jsFiddle automatically adds HTML5 DOCTYPE which also requires adding `margin-bottom:-5px;` per Pevara. It's not necessary if the DOCTYPE isn't there. If you add `margin-bottom:-5px` you should be good to go.

Comment: What is the DOCTYPE affecting, exactly? I see `margin-bottom:-5px` does fix the problem, but I don't understand why.

Comment: please do NOT omit your DTD (doctype). Doing this will trigger quirks mode in the browser and have it decide for itself how to best render the page, in stead of following the W3C standards. You'll end up with a cros browser nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

**Tested**: https://jsfiddle.net/2fax4vme/3/

```
.rhombus {
    height: 50px;
}
#navbar {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

I found there are few elements set to 50px in Bootstrap, so probably also make yours to the same height is a good plan to avoid editing those default values.