# Make one p tag full width in a div with padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following html code.

```css
body {
  background: lime !important;
}


/* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */

.mid-section {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5 px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.import-notes {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Testing </h1>
    <div class="mid-section">
      <p>(1)This is a test </p>
      <p>(2)This is a test </p>
      <p>(3)This is a test </p>
      <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would like make `<p class="import-notes">` to full width without padding.

Comment: its full witdth isnt it ??

Comment: If you don't want a padding in that tag, you must put the tag outside the div.mid-section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p class="import-notes">
```

already has full width but i think you want like this:

```css
body { background: lime !important; } /* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */
.mid-section { 
    padding:0 10px;
    background : white;
    border-color : black;        
    border-width: 5 px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.import-notes { 
    background : yellow; 
    margin-left:-10px;              
    margin-right:-10px;              
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Testing </h1>
  <div class="mid-section">
      <p>(1)This is a test </p>
      <p>(2)This is a test </p>
      <p>(3)This is a test </p>
      <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Workarounds:

One option would be to add these on `.import-notes`:

```
width: calc(100% + 20px)
position: relative;
left: -10px;
```

Or these, which is similar:

```
width: calc(100% + 20px);
margin-left: -10px;
```

Or just set two negative margins instead of one, so that you don't need to use `calc()`:

```
margin-left: -10px;
margin-right: -10px;
```

You can see them in action here:

```css
body {
  background: lime !important;
}

.mid-section {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5 px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.import-notes {
  /* OPTION 1 */
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  
  /* OPTION 2 */
  /* margin-left: -10px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px); */

  /* OPTION 3 */
  /* margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px; */

  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Testing </h1>
    <div class="mid-section">
      <p>(1)This is a test </p>
      <p>(2)This is a test </p>
      <p>(3)This is a test </p>
      <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### ✨ Actual Solution:

Alternatively, you could remove the padding from the parent and add it to the children, which looks to me more like an actual solution rather than a workaround.

What would happen if, for example, you change the `<p>` for `<a>`, which need to be clickable? You would need the padding to be inside it, not outside on the parent. Otherwise, the users won't be able to click on it on the sides, as they would be clicking on the parent instead.

```css
body {
  background: lime !important;
}

.mid-section {
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5 px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.mid-section > p {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.mid-section > .import-notes {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Testing </h1>
    <div class="mid-section">
      <p>(1)This is a test </p>
      <p>(2)This is a test </p>
      <p>(3)This is a test </p>
      <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `display:inline-block`. You can achieve it.

```
.import-notes {
  background: yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: lime !important;
}


/* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */

.mid-section {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5 px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.import-notes {
  background: yellow;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Testing </h1>
    <div class="mid-section">
      <p>(1)This is a test </p>
      <p>(2)This is a test </p>
      <p>(3)This is a test </p>
      <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Best solution for this is `display:inline-block`, so it will occupy width as it's content width so there would be no extra padding as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can set negative margins to it, based on your parent element.

```
.import-notes {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 -10px; //negative margin based on parent element padding
}
```

See also: [How do negative margins in CSS work and why is (margin-top:-5 != margin-bottom:5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495200/how-do-negative-margins-in-css-work-and-why-is-margin-top-5-margin-bottom5)

```css
body {
  background: lime !important;
}


/* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */

.mid-section {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5 px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.import-notes {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Testing </h1>
    <div class="mid-section">
      <p>(1)This is a test </p>
      <p>(2)This is a test </p>
      <p>(3)This is a test </p>
      <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can insert padding to childrens instead of parent,like this:

```
.mid-section p:not(.import-notes) {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: lime !important;
}

/* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */

.mid-section {
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.mid-section p:not(.import-notes) {
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.import-notes {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Testing </h1>
    <div class="mid-section">
      <p>(1)This is a test </p>
      <p>(2)This is a test </p>
      <p>(3)This is a test </p>
      <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but keep in mind it can mess with lists' bullet points for example.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body { background: lime !important; } /* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */
.mid-section { 
    padding:10px 0px;
    background : white;
    border-color : black;        
    border-width: 5 px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.mid-section .note {
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
.import-notes { 
    background : yellow;
    margin: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Testing </h1>
  <div class="mid-section">
     <p class='note'>(1)This is a test </p>
     <p class='note'>(2)This is a test </p>
     <p class='note'>(3)This is a test </p>
     <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

remove the padding in .mid-section, and insert the margin into all the p childs except the p tag except .import-notes

Comment: I think is not a solution for this problem, this occupies the whole width of it's parent div, so preffered solution for this problem is `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Thank you, Jani!.   I think, we could solve some problem with different way.

Answer (score 0):

If by full width you mean width equal to the Text, you should give one more style to `.import-notes`, i.e `display: inline-block;`