# Outlook negative table margin

Tags: html, css, email, templates, outlook

Good evening,

i tried many ways, but I failed.
How can I add negative margin or simillar solution for tables/divs/... for outlook email template...

My live preview is here:
[Live preview - Outlook email html template](http://daniel.koptak.cz/email/)

But reuslt in Outlok looks like:
[Outlook email template result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQq7V.jpg)

How can i add negative margin or similar solution, how to position table to negative margin?
Negative margins in Outlook not works, i thing Outlook similar work as IE6...
For any advice I thank you many times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do negative margins in CSS work and why is (margin-top:-5 != margin-bottom:5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495200/how-do-negative-margins-in-css-work-and-why-is-margin-top-5-margin-bottom5)

Comment: I have problem with Outlook email template... negative margin not work... position absolute not work, position relative with top negative not work, background-image with background-position not work.... some other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for help on Stackoverflow, plase post your html code so we can offer some guidance. Posting a link for us to look over, then right-click is not helpful.

CSS support for Margin on Outlook is buggy. In Outlook, `margin` will not work. You can use `Margin` which works.

Keep in mind that email development is not Web development. Some of the standards you're expected to follow in web development do not exist.

For further guidance on what is supported with Outlook and other email clients, I suggest this excellent source:

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/margin/
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

**Absolute positioning**

Since you asked, absolute positioning doesn’t work in email. One reliable solution across all platforms are spacer tables to create a space.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td height="20" style="height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/

Good luck.