# About negative margin-bottom

Tags: html, css, margin

I was doing some experiments on margin-bottom, and found a small problem that I did not quite understand.

```css
.left {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Coding Coding Coding Coding Coding</div>
```

[image]

When I set it to margine-bottom: -50px, it looks like this.
[image]

The box has the same width and height and can be rendered, but I don't understand what the orange part of the picture represents. Why is it reduced by half?

One explanation I see is that margin-bottom is negative and does not shift, reducing its own height for CSS to read. But I do not understand the meaning of this sentence, what is called its own height for CSS to read? If you can understand this point, can you explain it?

Answer (score 1):

When a static element is given a negative margin on the bottom, it doesn’t move the element down. Instead, it pulls any succeeding element into the main element, overlapping it.

[image]

Further reading on this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11499018/1945030

Answer (score 0):

CSS margin creates distance between elements with positive values, and starts to overlap them with negative values. That orange looks like your inspector output showing you the inspected element's `margin`. Of course if you use positive `margin-bottom` the inspector will show orange below the element while negative `margin-bottom` is represented by the orange margin indicator showing the overlap that would result once this element is laying out with other elements in the DOM.