# how can i change the gap of only one element in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i am creating something with css flexbox and use gap to give spacing between elements but now i want to change the spacing of only one element like

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.items{
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  
}

.item-4{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items item-1"></div>
  <div class="items item-2"></div>
  <div class="items item-3"></div>
  <div class="items item-4"></div>
  <div class="items item-5"></div>
  <div class="items item-6"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to change the gap of blue box to 5px from 20px
is there any way to do this

Comment: I edited the answer, do you have a problem?

Comment: `gap` properties apply to the entire grid, you need to do some workaround to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- The `gap` property only applies to **flex-parents**, not flex-items (flex-parents use it to control the gap *between* their child flex-items).

  - <sub>(The `gap` property also applies to `display: grid;`, but that's off-topic in this QA)</sub>
- To adjust the spacing of flex-items use an overridden `margin` property instead.

  - For `flex-direction: horizontal` you'll want to set `margin-left` and `margin-right` (or `margin-inline-start` and `margin-inline-end`).
  - For `flex-direction: vertical` you'll want to set `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` (or `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end`).
  - To have a *larger effective gap* then set any positive margin value.

    - e.g. with `gap: 5px` and `margin-left: 1px` then the *effective gap* to the left will be `6px`.
  - To have a *smaller effective gap* then [set a **negative margin**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495200/how-do-negative-margins-in-css-work-and-why-is-margin-top-5-margin-bottom5) value.

    - e.g. with `gap: 5px` and `margin-left: -1px` then the *effective gap* to the left will be `4px`.
  - This approach won't work for items with `margin: auto`, but that's okay because `gap:` isn't useful with `auto` margins anyway.
  - Don't forget that you can also use `calc` and `--custom-properties` to make the CSS easier to read, and to mix units (e.g. `3.2em` margin with a `10px` effective gap adjustment).

---

In your case, there's 20px on either side of your items, so applying a `margin-left` of `-15px` will give you a `5px` left gap, and a `margin-right` of `-15px` will give you a `5px` right gap.

Which looks like this:

[image]

---

Like so:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.items{
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  
}

.item-4 {
  background: blue;
  margin-left: -15px; /* Adapt 20px gap to 5px */
  margin-right: -15px; /* Adapt 20px gap to 5px */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items item-1"></div>
  <div class="items item-2"></div>
  <div class="items item-3"></div>
  <div class="items item-4"></div>
  <div class="items item-5"></div>
  <div class="items item-6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this fundamentally going against one of the good things about flexbox: you set the axis and semantically, your flex items shouldn't have to worry about it?  If you set margin top/bottom and the flexbox changes to having column direction, your margin is now applied wrongly and should be left/right.  There really ought to be a "margin-before/margin-after" concept in flexbox for individual items.

Comment: I wish there was a way of doing this via the parent component. I updated this answer although it seems hacky.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.items{
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  
}

.item-4{
  background: blue;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items item-1"></div>
  <div class="items item-2"></div>
  <div class="items item-3"></div>
  <div class="items item-4"></div>
  <div class="items item-5"></div>
  <div class="items item-6"></div>
</div>
```