Negative margin-right in Opera while reducing viewport width
I am working on "Project Landing Page" from freecodecamp. Following is my code


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
}


#header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    height: 5rem;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#header-img {
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 19rem;
}

#nav-bar > a {
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    cursor: default;
}

main {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 4rem;
    border: 2px solid black;
}



main > h2, #form {
    text-align: center;
}

#form input[type="email"] {
     padding: 0.3em 6em 0.3em 0.5em;
}

#form input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: gold;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em 0.2em 1em;
}

#form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: coral;
}

div > h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

div > p {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#features {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 28%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

#video {
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

#pricing {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 3em;
    column-gap: 1.2em;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.price-tag {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 0 1 19rem;
    row-gap: 1em;
}

button {
    padding: 0.8em 1.1em;
    background-color:coral;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: aqua;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.price-category {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    width: 100%;
}

.price-category > h3 {
    text-align: center;
  }

.price {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.price-tag  p {
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    text-align: end;
    width: 950px;
    margin: 2em auto 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
}

footer > a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

footer > p {
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 955px) {
    footer {
        width: auto;
    }

    #pricing {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .price-tag {
        width: 20em;
    }

    
}
<header id="header">
        <img src="product-landing-page-logo.png" alt="product logo" id="header-img">
        <nav id="nav-bar">
            <a href="#features" class="nav-link">Features</a>
            <a href="#video" class="nav-link">HowItWorks</a>
            <a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <h2>Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</h2>

        <form action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="GET STARTED" id="submit">
        </form> 

          <section id="features">
            <div>
                <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
                <p>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p>
                <br><br>
            </div>

            

            <div>
                <h2>Fast Shipping</h2>
                <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
                <br><br>
            </div>


            <div>
                <h2>Quality Assurance</h2>
                <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</p>
                <br><br>
            </div>

          </section>

          <section>
            <iframe width="560" id="video" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/y8Yv4pnO7qc?si=6TmQlZHbZ_rJsacf&amp;controls=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </section>

          <section id="pricing">
            <div class="price-tag">
                <div class="price-category">
                    <h3 >TENOR TROMBONE</h3>
                </div>
                
                <p class="price">$600</p>
                
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
                </div>

                <button type="button">SELECT</button>
            </div>
            <div class="price-tag">
                <div class="price-category">
                    <h3 >BASS TROMBONE</h3>
                </div>
                
                <p class="price">$900</p>
                
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
                </div>

                <button type="button">SELECT</button>
            </div>
            <div class="price-tag">
                <div class="price-category">
                    <h3 >VALVE TROMBONE</h3>
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <p class="price">$1200</p>
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <p>Plays similar to a Trumpet</p>
                    <p>Great for Jazz Bands</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
                </div>
                

                <button type="button">SELECT</button>
            </div>
          </section>
    </main>

    <footer>

        <a href="#">Privacy</a>
        <a href="#">Terms</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>

        <p>Copyright 2016, Original Trombones</p>
    </footer>



As I reduce viewport width in Opera browser, at one point, I get following values for footer element.
Viewport width = 960px
Footer element width = 950px
Footer margin-right = -9px
Footer margin-left = 0px
Body border left = 2px
Body border right = 2px

I don't know how to interpret these numbers. How to add them up ? At this point, horizontal scroll bar appears at the bottom and part of the footer is outside the border of body element.

Can anybody check this code in Opera browser and comment ?
Thanks

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

@Paulie I was getting error when I tried to use code snippet. It was asking me to use Ctrl+K. I could not figure that out. Otherwise I always use code snippet. Should I try to edit the question ?

Just use the <> icon when you edit to add the HTML and CSS in the appropriate sections. Do not include anything that is not relevant to showing the issue.

since question is about responsive code, I will have to include entire HTML code

Why? Your question seems to be about the footer only.

actually when I separate footer in separate file and try to analyze it, I don't get these negative margin-right while reducing viewport width. That's why I was puzzled.  I could not reproduce that behavior. So, it has something to do with other elements in the layout.

For info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495200/how-do-negative-margins-in-css-work-and-why-is-margin-top-5-margin-bottom5
