# MVC3 Popup Dialog positioning

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, popup, positioning

I have an MVC3 C# .Net web app.  I have a popup dialog box defined in a .js file.  I am trying to get the popup to display in the center of the screen.  What is the property to do that.  I have tries position:'absolute' but no go.  Here's a snipet of my  jscript code

```
LdapDialog = {
    /*
    * Base URL for the app. Must be set prior to calling show (ideally in _Layout.cshtml).
    */
    baseUrl: "",

    title: "Lookup:  Search by Last Name",
    width: 375,
    height: 600,
    loading: $('<img src="' + $.getUrl('Content/Images/loading.gif') + '" />'), 
    dialogContainer: $('<div></div>'),
    position: $('absolute'),
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is this popup? Is it something you wrote or a 3rd party component?

Comment: @BNL...it's something our team wrote

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen

Comment: @BNL...thanks, I should be able to use that