# How to find the center of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  a div,I need to **show this div on the center of the screen** (ie viewable area) even while the user scrolled through the page.

so its style should be (for example)

```
{position:fixed; top:90px; left:150 px; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
```

Now i need to find the  value of left and top, so that the div will place in the center of the screen  (ie viewable area), for any page .

How can i find the value of left & top with a javascript or jquery ?

Comment: yes, but in that case div won'y come in the exact center of the screen

Comment: top: -50% left: -50%, there are a LOT of examples on google... center a div

Comment: jQuery function to center a div on the screen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?&q=how+to+center+a+div+with+css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`left:50%; top:50%;` puts you in the middle, then you apply a fixed width and height and set `margin-top` and `margin-left` to negative a half of that `width` and `height`.

Comment: But it doesn't position the div in the center of the page.

Comment: Actually width and height of the div is dynamic according to the content.And it won't work

Answer (score 2):

In order to center something with fixed positioning then you will need to know the height and width of the element.

You then just need to `margin-top` and `margin-left` to negative half of the `width` and `height` in order to center it.

E.g. this class would center and element that has 100px `height` and 200px `width`.

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

**Update:**
If you don't know the height and width of the element that needs to be centered ahead of page load then you'll need to use JavaScript to detect the size.

Here's a working example of how this can be done - http://jsfiddle.net/3Ag97/1/

Comment: But in my case, i don't able to know the height and width of the div.It will be dynamic according to the content

Comment: In which case you'll need to use javascript to establish the height and width at load time. See this working example http://jsfiddle.net/3Ag97/1/

Comment: Linto, you should put that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flexbox module, although it's not widely supported yet: http://jsfiddle.net/b7nrS/.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $box = $('#box');

var bw = $box.width() / 2;
var bh = $box.height() / 2;

var wh = $(window).height() / 2;
var ww = $(window).width() / 2;

$box.css({'left': ww-bw, "top": wh-bh})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mqMwj/

Answer (score 0):

```
function centerObject(selector) {
var x = $(window).height() - $(selector).height();
var y = $(window).width() - $(selector).width();
$(selector).css("left", y / 2).css("top", x / 2);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#divX {
    position: fixed; 
    left: 50%; 
    top: 50%; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    margin-left: -50px; 
    margin-top: -50px; 
    background-color: #0000FF;
}
```