# Isn't no way to vertical align text inside a div with fixed height?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

I know it works with table, but nowdays there is no way to auto vertical align (in the center) text? I can't believe it...

My [code](http://jsfiddle.net/WzWMs/) :

## HTML

```
<div class="content">
    This is my text
</div>​
```

## CSS

```
.content
{
    width:80px;
    height:150px;    
    background-color:#aeaeae;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` to your `div`, demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/AATnH/).

For this to work on IE7, you can use this: [another little link](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/). It detects when your browser is IE6/7, and replaces elements with `display: table-*;` with actual HTML tables.

Comment: SO answers should be more "self-contained", not dependent upon the status of external links to stay useful.

Comment: @Sparky672 The external link is a link to a plugin. Should I just post the contents of the HTC in my answer?

Comment: @Abody97 Why do you prefer meaningless link text?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a site with multiple options and the assessments of each.  I've used the table based one with good success.

http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Comment: SO answers should be more "self-contained", not dependent upon the status of external links to stay useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content
{
    width:80px;
    height:150px;    
    background-color:#aeaeae;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This should help

Comment: Yeah, that won't work on IE7!

Comment: OK, but nothing was said about supporting so ancient versions of IE. And by default, I think, IE8+ is quite enough.