# Create Conetent Panel in middle of page

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I would like to create a content panel that is in the absolute middle of the page. It can expand both its width and height to a certain percent of the page before scrollbars appear.

I am using Primefaces on a JSF page. I am sure there are many solutions out there to do this. I would like to use JSF's composition.

Here is my solution:

```
<p:layout id="layout">
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <p:panel header="Test" style="width:50%">
                <ui:insert name="content"/>
            </p:panel>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
```

However, this doesn't really do anything. Its not centered, what ever I insert into the "content" tag expands to the whole page.

Can anyone assist on how I might accomplish my goal?

EDIT

I have tried the solution posted by Rick Calder. Below is my code. It however does not work for me. I wrote the css into the style.css. I wrote the javascript into resizeContentPanel.js. I load JQUery and the resizeContentPanel.js in the head of my resource.xhtml. I believe these are all the correct steps. Is there anything I could be missing.

As for what i actually wrong, I do not see the content panel. When I debug the javascript, it has a height-margin of -71 and a width-margin of -160. I am assuming this is why I cant see it.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>
        <ui:insert name="windowTitle"/>
    </title>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h:outputScript library="scripts" name="resizeContentPanel.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div class="centeredPanel">
        <p:layout id="layout" >
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <ui:insert name="content"/>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </div>

    <h:form>
        <div id="stack">
            <p:stack id="stackMenu" icon="/resources/images/stack/stack.png" model="#{pageBuilder.stackMenuModel}" /> 
        </div>
    </h:form>

    <div id="dock">
        <p:dock id="dockMenu" model="#{pageBuilder.dockMenuModel}"/>
    </div>

</h:body>
```

style.css

```
root 
{ 
    display: block;
}

body
{
    background-image: url('../../resources/images/background/background.jpg');
}

.centeredPanel{
    width:25%;
    height:25%;
    min-width:100px;
    min-height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}​
```

resizeContentPanel.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var heightMargin =  -($('.centeredPanel').height()/2);
var widthMargin=  -($('.centeredPanel').width()/2);
$('.centeredPanel').css('margin-left',widthMargin);
$('.centeredPanel').css('margin-top',heightMargin);
});

$(window).resize(function(){
var heightMargin =  -($('.centeredPanel').height()/2);
var widthMargin=  -($('.centeredPanel').width()/2);
$('.centeredPanel').css('margin-left',widthMargin);
$('.centeredPanel').css('margin-top',heightMargin);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perfectly centre something in the page you really want it to be a fixed size so you can do the calculations.

```
.centeredPanel{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; //sets left edge at the midway point of it's container
    top:50%; //sets top edge at the midway point of it's container
    margin-left:-250px; //moves the div back half it's width to centre it.
    margin-top:-250px; //moves the div up half it's height to centre it.
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/qNNvb/

To do it with percentages requires jQuery.

```
.centeredPanel{
    width:25%;
    height:25%;
    min-width:100px;
    min-height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    background-color:red;
}​


$(document).ready(function(){
var heightMargin =  -($('.centeredPanel').height()/2);
var widthMargin=  -($('.centeredPanel').width()/2);
$('.centeredPanel').css('margin-left',widthMargin);
$('.centeredPanel').css('margin-top',heightMargin);
});

$(window).resize(function(){
var heightMargin =  -($('.centeredPanel').height()/2);
var widthMargin=  -($('.centeredPanel').width()/2);
$('.centeredPanel').css('margin-left',widthMargin);
$('.centeredPanel').css('margin-top',heightMargin);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/qNNvb/3/

Comment: Awesome, thank! Is it possible to do the height and width as a percentage of the page. Like I want it to take up 75 percent of the width and 50 percent of the height. Would this be possible?

Comment: I think if you want to use percentages you're going to need to use javascript to calculate the height and width and set the margins appropriately. I can't think of another way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I have tried to implement it. Will you please take a look at my EDIT above. I cant seem to get it to display correctly.

Comment: the code is actually jQuery and I do believe it has to go in the page itself rather than in an external js file.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Apparently Primefaces adds jqury automatically. So when I added again, it caused all sorts of things to go wrong. Your solution worked fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use JQuery to center the page. Does this solution work?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/210733/1285564