# Centering image at all times

Tags: html, css, image, center, graphical-logo

I have an image, which i'm using as a logo.

I want this to be centered at all times (regardless of window size).

I haven't been able to do this with auto margins.

The image has to go over the bottom of my nav, which is placed above the logo.

HTML:

```
<div id="logo">

<img src="images/logorz.png" alt="logo" width="180px" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:41%;
    margin-top:-7%;


}
```

NAV HTML:

```
<div id="nav">

<ul>
    <li><img src="images/kranznav.png" alt="kranz" /><a href="index.php">COMPETE</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/thumbnav.png" alt="thumb" /><a href="index.php">SCORE</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/bagnav.png" alt="bag" /><a href="index.php">SHOP</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/morenav.png" alt="more" /><a href="index.php">MORE</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

NAV CSS:

```
#nav {
    background:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-2em;

}


#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

#nav li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-right:2%;
    margin-top:5%;
    text-align:center;
}



#nav a {
    display:block;
    margin-right:0% auto;
    padding-left:0% auto;
    color:#5E09CB;
    text-decoration:none;
```

}

Comment: You can do it by using jquery, look at; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use javascript for this.

You can do it this way:

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    width:100px;


}
```

Note, that the element needs to have a width, and the negative left margin is half the width.

http://jsbin.com/ukexox/1/edit

Comment: Great - exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

if your logo is `width: 180px;` and you want to center it at all times. You can do it like this.

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -90px;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the image to be on top of the nav, then try using z-index property...

something like this...

```
css {

z-index:2;

}
```

use z-index to position one element over the other... make sure you give the z-index of the other element lesser than this...

This might work...

Answer (score 0):

```
#logo {
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:180px;
}
```

`auto` sets the left and right margin automatically, so the `#logo` is always centered within the page... some browsers need `position:relative` to get this work...

Comment: Using position relative, doesn't make the logo overlap the bottom of the nav. Instead, it displays within the nav, increasing the height of the nav

Comment: yeah, You are right... sorry for that! the solution by Chanckjh should be the finest...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a wrapper which wraps both nav and image. The image tag need not be surrounded with the unnecessary div. Then, you can style the image as

```
image {
    position:relative;
    widhth: image_size_here px;
    margin: auto;
    display:block;

}
```

Here is a jsfiddle I saved for your reference... http://jsfiddle.net/vASmC/