# Center an element directly in the center of screen. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just want to center the blue box directly in the center of the screen using jquery.

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pxjkk/

```
<html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? This JSFiddle pertains to your previous question... It seems you're getting us to build your project bit by bit.

Comment: Seems like you got the "post some code in the question instead of just linking to JSfiddle" message, in that case you should post code related to the question instead of a random tag.

Comment: please search before you ask !!! http://bit.ly/XdUUjs

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/210717/1331430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center your blue box, it's position has to be set to `position:absolute;`

if your blue box changes size dynamically, you have to center it using javascript.

Here is a quick example:

```
$('#color')
    .css('top','50%')
    .css('left','50%')
    .css('margin-left','-'+($('#color').outerWidth()/2)+'px')
    .css('margin-top','-'+($('#color').outerHeight()/2)+'px');
```

Make sure it stays center on browser resize:

```
$(document).bind('resize', function(){
        $('#color')
        .css('top','50%')
        .css('left','50%')
        .css('margin-left','-'+($('#color').outerWidth()/2)+'px')
        .css('margin-top','-'+($('#color').outerHeight()/2)+'px');
    });
```

It will probably be a good idea to wrap the centering code into a function and call it whenever the size of the blue box changes.

Here is the edited jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mdkpS/

Answer (score 0):

Basics of centering elements in css:

- Make a container for your element and put it at `body` level (to center in the middle of the screen)
- Set `position: relative` on the container
- Set `position: absolute` on the element
- Add fixed `width` and `height` to the element
- Set `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` on element
- Set `margin-left` and `margin-top` to negative half the `width` and `height` respectively

The same logic applies for jQuery, only that you can calculate dimensions and margins dynamically.

Comment: I know css. I believe the question specifies using jQuery.

Comment: The same logic applies for jQuery.