# Centering div elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some div elements which when I click on them, they show their back (flipcards) and expand to a size of 600px by 600px, I want those divs to also go in the center of the screen when I click on it, then move back again when a click on it again. I would like it to be centered horizontally and vertically. I have tried searching, and so far none of them worked. Most results included something such as:

```
.flip.cover.flipped{
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    top: 50%;
}
```

I've added that to the current css class`.flip.cover.flipped` which is a class which is toggled on click using javascript, but that only resulted in my div elements to remain where it was on click. See this. Here is the `.flip.cover.flipped` class in full:

```
.flip .cover.flipped {
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: rotatey(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotatey(180deg);
        -o-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Other results included a custom javascript function, which I couldn't test out. If a custom javascript function works, I just need something to toggle it with (If that's the case, I'm really hoping for something simple such as `$(this).find('.cover').toggleClass('flipped');`, only for functions)

I'd really appreciate anyone's help as to how I'd be able to do this.

---

I've recently discovered that the usual way centres the element within its parent element. Problem is that I want to centre the element within the window not within its parent element.
Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="flip">
    <div class="cover">
        <div class="face front">
            <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3809/8814925510_b53d082ea6_o.jpg" width="125"/>
        </div>
        <div class="face back">
            Hello World!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the javascript to toggle the class:

```
        $('.flip').click(function() {
            $(this).find('.cover').toggleClass('flipped');
        });
```

**Edit:** I was reviewing some of my own questions, and since the link to my example has been changed, I decided on showing the full code of the page here along with the result:

```js
$('.flip').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.cover').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
            /*Sorted alphabetically*/
            * {
              margin: 0px;
              padding: 0px;
            }
            #backbutton {
              background-image: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8538/8781018857_feef1c4e6e_o.png");
              background-position: center;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: 90px 32px;
              color: #FFFFFA;
              display: inline-block;
              font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
              font-size: 26px;
              float: left;
              min-width: 90px;
              padding: 4px 0px;
              text-align: center;
              text-shadow: 0px -0.9px 1px #1e160a, -0.9px 0px 1px #1e160a, 0.9px 0px 1px #f5eee2, 0px 0.9px 1px #f5eee2;
              z-index: 2;
            }
            body {
              background-image: url('http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2891/8769949843_f6b2b03c89_o.png');
              background-repeat: repeat-y;
              background-position: 0px 37px;
              background-size: cover;
            }
            #creditsbutton {
              background-image: url("http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3726/8769949955_3d28f7be67_o.png");
              background-position: center;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: 100px 32px;
              color: #FFFFFA;
              display: inline-block;
              font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
              font-size: 26px;
              float: right;
              min-width: 100px;
              padding: 4px 0px;
              text-align: center;
              text-shadow: 0px -0.9px 1px #1e160a, -0.9px 0px 1px #1e160a, 0.9px 0px 1px #f5eee2, 0px 0.9px 1px #f5eee2;
              z-index: 2;
            }
            .flip {
              box-shadow: 0px 15px 6px -6px #2C0600;
              -o-box-shadow: 0px 15px 6px -6px #2C0600;
              -ms-box-shadow: 0px 15px 6px -6px #2C0600;
              -moz-box-shadow: 0px 15px 6px -6px #2C0600;
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 15px 6px -6px #2C0600;
              display: inline-block;
              height: 185px;
              position: relative;
              width: 125px;
              perspective: 800;
              -o-perspective: 800;
              -moz-perspective: 800;
              -ms-perspective: 800;
              -webkit-perspective: 800;
            }
            .flip .cover {
              height: 100%;
              padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
              position: relative;
              text-align: center;
              width: 100%;
              transform-style: preserve-3d;
              -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
              -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
              -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
              -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
              transition: 0.5s;
              -o-transition: 0.5s;
              -moz-transition: 0.5s;
              -ms-transition: 0.5s;
              -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
            }
            .flip .cover .back {
              background: white;
              color: black;
              cursor: pointer;
              transform: rotatey(-180deg);
              -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
              -ms-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
              -o-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
              -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
            }
            .flip .cover.flipped {
              left: 50%;
              margin-top: -300px;
              margin-left: -300px;
              position: absolute;
              height: 600px;
              width: 600px;
              top: 50%;
              transform: rotatey(-180deg);
              -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
              -ms-transform: rotatey(180deg);
              -o-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
              -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
              z-index: 10;
            }
            .flip .cover .face {
              font-family: Helvetica, Sans Serif;
              height: 100%;
              line-height: 200px;
              position: absolute;
              text-align: center;
              width: 100%;
              backface-visibility: hidden;
              -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
              -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
              -ms-backfae-visibility: hidden;
              -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            }
            .flip .cover .front {
              background: black;
              color: white;
              cursor: pointer;
              position: absolute;
            }
            #header {
              background-image: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8137/8774763204_453c37e1aa_o.png");
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: cover;
              min-width: 673px;
              padding: 4px 14px;
              z-index: 1;
            }
            .headerbuttonsegment-centre {
              background-image: url("http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5330/8787597480_6696f22a79_o.png");
              background-position: center;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              color: #FFFFFA;
              display: inline-block;
              font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
              font-size: 26px;
              padding: 4px 0px;
              text-align: center;
              text-shadow: 0px -0.9px 1px #1e160a, -0.9px 0px 1px #1e160a, 0.9px 0px 1px #f5eee2, 0px 0.9px 1px #f5eee2;
              z-index: 2;
            }
            #headerbuttonsegment-left {
              background-image: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8560/8787597614_733a58b275_o.png");
              background-position: center;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              color: #FFFFFA;
              display: inline-block;
              font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
              font-size: 26px;
              padding: 4px 0px;
              text-align: center;
              text-shadow: 0px -0.9px 1px #1e160a, -0.9px 0px 1px #1e160a, 0.9px 0px 1px #f5eee2, 0px 0.9px 1px #f5eee2;
              z-index: 2;
            }
            #headerbuttonsegment-right {
              background-image: url("http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5466/8787597568_43fd6869fb_o.png");
              background-position: center;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              color: #FFFFFA;
              display: inline-block;
              font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
              font-size: 26px;
              padding: 4px 0px;
              text-align: center;
              text-shadow: 0px -0.9px 1px #1e160a, -0.9px 0px 1px #1e160a, 0.9px 0px 1px #f5eee2, 0px 0.9px 1px #f5eee2;
              z-index: 2;
            }
            #shelf {
              list-style-type: none;
              padding: 10px 50px 20px;
              position: relative;
            }
            .spacing {
              display: inline-block;
              width: 50px;
            }
            .wrap-centre {
              min-width: 603px;
              text-align: center;
              width: 100%
            }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id='header'>
    <a href="http://markscamilleri.tumblr.com">
      <div id="backbutton">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Back
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class='wrap-centre'>
      <div id="headerbuttonsegment-left" style=" min-width: 150px; background-size: 150px 32px;">
        &nbsp;Bookshelf&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="headerbuttonsegment-centre" style=" min-width: 175px; background-size: 175px 32px;">
        Want to Read
      </div>
      <div id="headerbuttonsegment-right" style=" min-width: 150px; background-size: 150px 32px;">
        Favourites
      </div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div id='creditsbutton'>
          Credits
          <!--Do not remove Credits!!-->
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="shelf">
    <div class="flip">
      <div class="cover">
        <div class="face front">
          <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2866/8804333739_9d644bcdf6_o.jpg" width="125" />
        </div>
        <div class="face back">
          Hello World!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacing">
    </div>
    <div class="flip">
      <div class="cover">
        <div class="face front">
          <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3809/8814925510_b53d082ea6_o.jpg" width="125" />
        </div>
        <div class="face back">
          Hello World!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: that css should work fine, however it will center based on the first parent that has position absolute or relative. If you just want to center in the middle of the viewport, you could use `position: fixed`

Comment: it's parent, `.cover` was `relative`, I changed it to `fixed` yet it still didn't worked (it stayed the same).

Comment: your url doesn't work no more

Comment: oh, sorry, I changed it.. it is http://jnwtson.tumblr.com/themetest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flip animation is likely to need a lot of work, but I think I've got the centering issue worked out.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/f84Js/12/)**

```
$(function () {
    $('.flip').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.cover').toggleClass('flipped');
        centered();
    });
    centered = function () {
        var wy = window.innerHeight / 2,
            wx = window.innerWidth / 2,
            py = 300,
            px = 300,
            pageTop = wy - py,
            pageLeft = wx - px;
        if ($('.cover').hasClass('flipped')) {
            $('.flipped').css({
                position: "absolute",
                top: pageTop,
                left: pageLeft
            });
        } else {
            $('.flip, .cover').removeAttr('style');
        }
    };
    $(window).resize(centered);
});
```

Comment: thanks. Is there any way to make the movement a bit more fluid?

Comment: @markscamilleri you'll have to play with the css. I think if you smooth out the flip the rest will look ok.

Comment: smooth out the flip, in what sense?

Comment: @markscamilleri http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/f84Js/24/embedded/result/  I played with it a little more and slowed it down so you could see what's happening. I think I've worked out most of the issues except the initial jump to position absolute... Not sure what to do with that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but try with Jquery :)

Create a `.centermybox` DIV.

**Css**:

```
.centermybox{
      position:absolute;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      z-index:99;
      margin: -300px 0 0 -300px;
}
```

**Jquery** :

```
$(document).ready function() {
     $(".youdivhere").toggle( function() {
         $(this).addClass(".centermybox"); 
     });
});
```

Comment: Just like I said, the css isn't working properly, look at the link in the question to see the results with that css.

Comment: With this the div centres by placing the top-left corner in the centre of the original div box like [here](http://jnwtson.tumblr.com/themetest2)

Comment: I've recently discovered that the usual way centres the element within its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I spotter two problems

1. Your div with class `flip` has a `position:relative` so the cover is absolute to this and not the `shelf`.
2. Your margin-left and margin-top are not calculated correctly. You need to calculate these according to screen and modal size

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen) is a way to center a div using jquery

This working correctly depends heavily on 1. above

Comment: 1. If I change that, the cards would go into each other, not so nice.

2. How should I calculate them please?

Comment: regarding 1 don't you open only one cover at a time?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to do that but I still haven't searched for that, one step at a time.

Comment: oh, I now see what you meant, sorry.... If I change the `position` to `relative`, the cards **before I flip them** would go into each other.

Comment: how do I toggle it on click?

Comment: probably using `toggleClass` in jquery

Comment: I don't think it will work as the result in the link you posted is using javascript...

Comment: I've recently discovered that the usual way centres the element within its parent element. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the body

```
body {
  height:100%;
}
```

and this to the `flipped` class (changing what is necessary):

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-300px;
margin-left:-300px;
```

You can animate the motion using javascript/jQuery, but I assume you know how to do that. Please comment if you have no clue

EDIT: [Here is a jsFiddle showing it works](http://jsfiddle.net/f84Js/)

On a side note you should probably use margins for the spacing in between each book (aka `margin-right:50px;`, etc.), not another element

**Edit 2**: Since you're using jQuery already, you can change your jQuery on click function to this:

```
$('.flip').click(function() {
    var midHeight = window.innerHeight/2;
    var midWidth = window.innerWidth/2;
    $(this).find('.cover').toggleClass('flipped').css({
        "position":"absolute",
        "top":midHeight,
        "left":midWidth,
        "margin-top":"-300px",
        "margin-left":"-300px"
    });
});
```

[With the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f84Js/2/) to prove it works too. However with this method you have would have to do the same type of calculation on window resize if you want it to stay perfectly centered as in

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var midHeight = window.innerHeight/2;
    var midWidth = window.innerWidth/2;
    $(this).find('.cover').toggleClass('flipped').css({
        "top":midHeight,
        "left":midWidth
    });
});
```

But this takes more to process

Keep in mind you need to change the position back to the original value on the next click

**Edit three:**

Since it seems you don't have enough basic jQuery knowledge to apply what I have given you correctly, [here is a fully working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f84Js/3/). You *should* be able to switch out the class names/lines I have for the commented out lines and it work, though without directly manipulating your code there could be a couple small errors that you *should* be able to fix yourself

As for animating the transition, I approximated the result [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f84Js/4/) by simply moving some of the `.css` to `.animate`s. You can play around with it to get it functioning a little better

If you're unsure of what anything that I added does, or you have some error you can't resolve after some time of working on it including looking up similar problems, comment and I will try to assist you further

Comment: I don't know how to animate that... I'm still starting html, css and javascript... above all, it didn't work. The result is: http://jnwtson.tumblr.com/themetest3

Comment: Oh, and thanks about the margin to space the book, will do. (Sry, but the link posted doesn't have that yet.) Also, the result is like that as it is centring within the parent element. I want to centre it within the window.

Comment: I know that it works, just that it centres the element relative to the parent element not to the page. I need it to be in the centre of the page not of its parent element. See the HTML structure above

Comment: From what I can tell, the div layer `flip` is useless, simply apply the click event to the div layer `cover`. Or you can do what my second edit suggests

Comment: Actually, if I place the click event on the div layer `cover`, it won't work. Also, how to I revert it back to its original position?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know I need to learn :) , I'm a very basic beginner.

Comment: Thanks, but even while meddling, it either just has the second one move to the centre and the first one off centre, or turns and goes to the centre without animation. Here are the two versions:

Comment: Then it is an implementation issue on your part, I'm sorry I can't help you any more with the information I have

Comment: The one that moves only: http://pastebin.com/1tws6WNK - http://jnwtson.tumblr.com/themetest4

The one that has no animation: http://pastebin.com/RzHzD8PJ  - http://jnwtson.tumblr.com/themetest5

Comment: The thing is that because your code is poorly constructed in the fist place (with unnecessary CSS, unnecessary elements, etc.) and because you don't fully understand the languages you're using you will continue to run into problems all along the way. I would recommend learning the languages better to start, then restructuring the program, only using snippets from this version to help for little things