# Centering reative to div block

Tags: html, css

I have div block which contains form as the following:

```
<div class="divClass">
    <form id="frm" method="post" action="/NotDefinedYet/index.xhtml" class="frmClass">
        <input type="text" name="j_idt9:j_idt10:Username" placeholder="Username">
    </form>
</div>
```

corresponding `css`-stylesheet

```
.divClass{
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
}
.frmClass{
    position: relative;        
    margin:auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 280px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Eventually i have only horizontl centering form relative to `div` block. But I need to centering both **vertical and horizontal**. How it can be implemented?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css) out

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.divClass{
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
    text-align:center;
}
.frmClass{
    position: relative;        
    margin:0 auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 280px;
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 50%;
}
```

And see this link http://jsfiddle.net/bipin_kumar/DmMVd/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85UFc/))

```
.divClass{
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
}
.frmClass{
    position: absolute;        
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -75px;
    margin-left: -140px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

It works because:

1. An `absolute` component inside a `relative` container is layed out relatively to the container, therefore specifying top as `50%` will  place the component's top position at the middle of the container;
2. Given we know the height of the component, once we specify `margin-top` as -half that height, the component will be exactly at the center of the container.

Same is applied to horizontally center the component.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite way **if you don't need legacy browser support**. I like it because it is independent of parent and child container sizes.

http://jsfiddle.net/samih/K4kLj/

```
.divClass{
    position: relative;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
}
.frmClass{
    width: 280px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
}
```

Works in IE9+, chrome and firefox. See http://caniuse.com/#search=transform for a full list of browser support.

Answer (score -2):

place the form inside center tag.

div

center

form

form will be aligned in the middle inside the div

Comment: The <center> element is deprecated in HTML 4.01.