# How can I vertically center a div without knowing the parent height?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, center, absolute

Hello I hope you can help me. I'm trying to vertically center a div but I keep failing.
I think the problem is that the div is a gallery composed of 2 elements
- the main images which are not scrollable because they fit the screen 
- the thumbnails (that appear through jquery hide/show and hide the main images clicking on     the specific icon).
I can't center the child div (the gallery) because I can't set a height to the parent (page container) because I need the thumbnails to be scrollable. but I want the main images to be centered in the page...

here's my html code (I kept the essential):

```
<!--page -->
<div id="gallery-container">

<!-- main images -->        
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
<img src="img.jpg">  
</div>

<!-- thumbnails -->
<div class="thumbs">
<img src="img.jpg">
</div>

<!-- jquery hide/show code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.thumbsicon').on('click', function() {
$('.cycle-slideshow').hide(); $('.thumbs').fadeIn();
});
$('.thumbs li img').on('click', function() {
var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');   
$('.cycle-slideshow').fadeIn('slow').css('background-image', 'url( + imgSrc + )');
$('.thumbs').hide(); 
});
</script>
</div>
```

And the css (consider that my website has a 250px sidebar menu on the left):

```
#gallery-container{width:700px;z-index:70;margin:0   auto;position:relative;overflow:hidden;padding:0 20px 0 270px;}

.cycle-slideshow {width:700px;height:517px;margin:0 auto;padding:0;position:relative;}

.thumbs {position:relative; width:700px; margin:0 auto; padding:0; display:none;}
```

I tried many css solutions but none seems to be working. What can I do? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a stackoveflow that I adapted the accepted answer's code from for my own purposes a while back. Here's what I have to position to the window or to the parent element:

[Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6P7AM/1/

```
jQuery.fn.center = function (centerToWindow) {
    var parent = null;
    var positionCss = null;
    if (centerToWindow) {
        parent = window;
        positionCss = "absolute";
    } else {
        parent = this.parent();
        positionCss = "relative";
    }
    this.css({
        "position": positionCss,
            "top": Math.max(0, (($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop()) + "px",
            "left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
    });
    return this;
}

$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $("#gallery-container").center(true);
    }).trigger("resize");
});
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try this and let you know!

Comment: Works great!I don't know why I didn't think about using jQuery, thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

On the parent containing the elements you would like to center, set these CSS properties.

display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;

Comment: Thank you but I have already tried this and unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Try applying position relative to the parent container, and absolute position to what you need centered. Then for the centered element, apply these CSS properties: position:absolute;top:50%;

Answer (score 0):

You should find what you want in this post : http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the parent height, you can get it in jQuery with

```
var parentHeight = $('#gallery-container').height();
```

then you can use `parentHeight` throughout your code to help you center like so:

```
var parentHeight = $('#gallery-container').height();
$('#gallery-container').css('margin-top', '-' + (parentHeight + 'px');
```

and then of course you'd have to have this in your css:

```
#gallery-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

make sure you call this centering code on `$(document).ready();` of course, but also on `$(window).resize();`

Comment: Thank you I'll try this and let you know!