# Jquery dialog open at center of another dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I want to open a jquery dialog at the center of parent dialog.
I am able to get parent dialog at center, but I am not able to get dialog of another dialog at center

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

If you're centering the parent dialog using absolute positioning ( eg [Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen) ), what you'll have to do is put a relatively-positioned element inside of your "absolutely-positioned" parent dialog.

Example:

```
<div id="absolutely_centered_parent" class="dialog">
    <div id="relative_child_container">
        <div id="absolutely_centered_child" class="dialog">
        <!-- Child content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```