# jquery returning different height everytime I reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a light box kind of thing in jQuery. For vertically aligning my lightbox,I am using jQuery. Here is my plugin code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.lightbox = function(){
        return this.each(function(){

            /*plugin code starts here*/

            var self = this;
            console.log(self);

            /*
            * Now we will vertically align the lightbox
            * To do that we will calculate the body's height,lightboxes height
            * and then subtract later from earlier one.This will give us the total empty space
            * So the margin from the top of lightbox will be half of the result we got from subtraction
            */
            //calculating body's height
            var doc_body_height = $('body').height();
            var lightbox_height = $(self).height();
            var margin_top = (doc_body_height - lightbox_height)/2;
            $(self).css('margin-top',margin_top);
            console.log($(self).height());
            /*plugin code ends here*/

        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

But the problem is, I am getting either 18 or 300 as height. 300 is the actual height of the  div#lightbox,I don't know why the same function is returning different heights randomly.

See Image:
[image]

Clearly the div#lightbox is not 18px in height.

Comment: Are you calling your plugin when document is ready or how? I think this is not problem of your plugin. Also, you may round your final value.

Comment: You want the window height not the body height too.

Comment: [**Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?  It would be helpful to see how you are calling your plugin and how the page in which it is being used is designed, including the css.  I suspect the issue might originate in  the fact that the jQuery height() method returns the computed value of the element.  That means that a hidden element (display: none) for example will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the height using the `$('body').height()`.  This is the computed value for the height of the body element.   That means that for a page with just one visible element that is 50px high on it, the body will return 50px.  Conversely, a long page that requires lots of scrolling will return the entire body height, not just the portion that is visible in the viewport.

You need to use `$(window).height();` in your calculation instead.

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is, I am getting either 18 or 300 as height. 300 is
>   the actual height of the div#lightbox,I don't know why the same
>   function is returning different heights randomly -Rajat Saxena

At original post

```
 var self = this;
 console.log(self);

 var lightbox_height = $(self).height();
```

`window.innerHeight` appear to return `viewport` of `window` . See [Window.innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerHeight) .

Try, at `console` , this page , while periodically adjusting `console` "height" , and within piece at original post

```
console.log($(window).height()
             , $(self).height()
             , $(window)[0].innerHeight
             , $(window).height() === $(self).height()
             , $(this).height());
```

Comment: If I constantly reload the page,sometimes my original function returns 18,sometimes it returns 300.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only supporting modern browsers then you could use CSS and take advantage of a flexbox http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I love modern browsers,but the client wants to support IE 9 also.